# How to set the input value in a modal dialogue?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, jquery-events

I'm working on 'add a link' functionality. For that I'm using [Modal plugin from Twitter Boostrap JS](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modal). On the main page there's only the 'link' field to fill, when a user clicks 'add link' button, a modal pops up, and the user sees the complete form to fill 3 fields: link, title, tags. However, I want the link field to be pre-filled with the value from the previous step. It's similar to what happens when you 'save a link' on delicious.com.

Thanks to Joe's help ([previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845107/how-to-propagate-the-text-field-to-the-modal-dialogue/)) I can print the linkURL on the modal dialogue, but it's important that this linkURL is the value of the link field of the form with 3 fields (link, title, tags). Any idea how this can be done?

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('#modal-from-dom').bind('show',function()
                {
                    $(".modal-body").html($("#linkURL").val());
                });
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- The Modal Dialog  -->
          <div id="modal-from-dom" class="modal hide fade">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
                <h3>Add Link</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <!--
            <form id='post-on-wall' method='POST' action='savePost.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>"
        <input type='text' class='label-inline' name='linkURL' id='wall-post' value=linkURL>
            </form>
            -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn primary">Add Link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wall-post">
        <textarea class='label-inline' name='linkURL' id='linkURL'></textarea>
        <button data-controls-modal="modal-from-dom" data-backdrop="true" data-keyboard="true" class="btn">Add Link</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
      $('#modal-from-dom').bind('show',function()
            {
                $(".modal-body #wall-post").val($("#linkURL").val());
            });
```

or am i missing something? :)

Comment: its not working for me .bind is not firing $('#edit-child-modal').bind('shown', function () {
        $(".modal-content #Name").val('test');
    });