# How to call a Bootstrap Modal in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-3, bootstrap-modal

I created a sample project that whenever i click a button link, it should call a View which contains my Modal Pop Up. I was able to call the View but the modal in it doesn't appear. What can i do to fix it? Can anybody help me please?

This is my code. The link should call the "Create_Business_Info" that contains the modal

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Business_Info";
}

<div class="container-fluid">

    <a href='@Url.Action("Create_Business_Info", "Maintenance")'>
    Business INFO!
    </a>

    </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myModal").show();

    });

</script>
```

This is the code of the Modal that should appear.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" data-     keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog ">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header modal-header-employee">

            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;    </button>
            <h3 class="modal-title">Business Information</h3>
        </div>
        <br />

        <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Business Name:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Address:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Contact No:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Website:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Email Address:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--modal body-->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>

            </div><!--modal footer-->
        </div><!--modal content-->
    </div><!--modal dialog-->
</div><!--business_info-->



<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myModal").show();

    });



</script>
```

Someone help me please. Thank you so much.

Comment: `Create_Business_Info that contains the modal` is this a partial view?

Comment: No it isn't. This just render the Layout page.

Comment: No i mean this one. `<a href='@Url.Action("Create_Business_Info", "Maintenance")'>`

Comment: follow this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231862/using-bootstrap-modal-window-as-partialview

Comment: It's not a partial view Sir.

Comment: can you specify the filenames in which this codes are located? im assuming that the link and the modal are in the same page. Its confusing since you are saying that the action link will not call partial view and it contradicts on the description `View which contains my Modal Pop Up`

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista have you added the `bootstrap.min.js` file?

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista  https://dotnetfiddle.net/xZYtjr

Comment: Im so sorry for the confusion my question brought to you Sir. What i'm saying is that,   <a href='@Url.Action("Create_Business_Info", "Maintenance")'>
    Business INFO!
    </a>                 is located in another page. Once this link is clicked, another page will be called. This page is the Modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your script to ,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
    });
</script>
```

it should be  `selector.modal('show')` instead of `selector.show()`
Source:[Launch Bootstrap Modal on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233550/launch-bootstrap-modal-on-page-load)

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: this function works as per the source i have mentioned , along with the window.load function

Comment: .modal('show')

Manually opens a modal. Returns to the caller before the modal has actually been shown (i.e. before the shown.bs.modal event occurs).

Copy
$('#myModal').modal('show')

Comment: @REDEVI_29 yes got your point, please read the requirement modal should show after clicking the link

Comment: The script to be placed in the view which contains the modal

Comment: I followed your instruction Sir but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#myModal').modal();
```

Answer (score 0):

Main point to note is It should be

```
$('#myModal').modal('show')
```

Not

`$('#myModal').show();`

Here Check the **[Bootstrap Document](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods)**

Also **place the script in the View which has the modal**, So on load of this view with modal the modal is shown.

Also here is a working example below

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" data-     keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog ">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header modal-header-employee">

            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;    </button>
            <h3 class="modal-title">Business Information</h3>
        </div>
        <br />

        <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Business Name:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Address:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Contact No:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Website:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Email Address:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--modal body-->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>

            </div><!--modal footer-->
        </div><!--modal content-->
    </div><!--modal dialog-->
</div><!--business_info-->
```

Comment: I copied the code you provide. But still, it's not working :(

Comment: If its not working then might be you are missing something else in your code, may be something else is wrong in your code which you have not shown us. May be you are loading jquery files twice and this can be any random thing for not to work.. So see your console window and let me know what errors you find.