# Return View as a Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to return a modal from my controller post action of a previous modal. The issue I am having is that the partial view is not rendered as a modal. All the documentation I can find refers to opening a modal from a button, however my modal is conditional so I want the controller to handle whether or not to load the modal / which modal to load

**Part of partial view where I return the view containing the modal**

```
return PartialView("_AccountUpdateSuccess");
```

**My View**

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="updateSuccess">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Success!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="text-success">@ViewBag.Account has been updated successfully!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document)
        .ready(function() {
            $("#updateSuccess").modal('show');
        });
</script>
```

Comment: *The issue I am having is that the partial view is not rendered as a modal* ....How is it rendered?

Comment: It looks like a modal sort of but there is no pop-up. Just a white screen with the text/forms but not properly formatted

Comment: I think this post helpful to you  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231862/using-bootstrap-modal-window-as-partialview

Comment: How are you handling the controller response on the client side?

Comment: I have a little script tag in my view to render the modal. This seems to work when returning a view but not when returning a partial `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document)
        .ready(function() {
            $("#updateSuccess").modal('show');
        });
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

You would have to add the javascript into the **parent** view, as a call back from your ajax function and not in the partial view. The reason for this is that script tags added by an ajax call are not automatically run.

Comment: How would I trigger the show from the parent without using a click event?

Comment: You can still use a click even, you must simply bind it one level higher, using something like $("body").on(".selector", "click", function() {

Comment: I wouldnt actually use body, but the closest element already on the page. Read up on the on function: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I do not want to do it off of a click event. I want to do it off of a successful submit. So my submit will hit the controller. The controller will check some values and if successful load a success modal, otherwise reload the current modal with the validation messages

Comment: In that case refer to Javiers answer which shows you an ajax call. One of the parameters is called success and this is a function which is called after the submit. This is what i meant initially when I said a 'call back' as after the submit happens it 'calls back' this function that you have provided

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is to insert the response in an empty div where you can put it, for example, at the bottom of the shared layout. I use this method while returning `PartialView` without any issues.

Then I use this script to load a modal:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Controller/ActionWhichReturnsAPartialView",
    success: function (data) {
        $(".modal-backdrop").remove(); // I have to do this hack just in case of a modal calling another modal and to avoid some display issues with the overlayed background
        $("#temp").html(data); // #temp is the empty div
        $("#myModal").modal("show"); // myModal is the root div id of the html result
    }
```

Comment: This will work provided the ajax call is in the parent page and NOT the partial, which seems to be the OPs problem