# Pass Multiple Values to Bootstrap Modal Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have an html table of 'members' and on each row an 'edit' button.

The edit button opens a Bootstrap modal with a form.

I would like to pre-fill the form fields, based on the values (name, email, mobile) in the relevant row.  I used code from this answer (not the accepted answer but this function from @ajkochanowicz):

```
$('.header-link').click(function(e) {
$('.modal-header h4').html($(e.target).html())
})
```

[Passing Data to Bootstrap Modals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788609/passing-data-to-bootstrap-modals)

... but it only allows for a single value to be passed.

how can I pass multiple values to the modal form and inject them into the relevant fields in the modal form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why just do a function that fill your fields. The fact that you use a modal doesn't change anything

```
function fillFields(name, email, mobile){
    $("#field-name").value(name)
    $("#field-email").value(email)
    $("#field-mobile").value(mobile)
}
$("#my-modal").show()
```