# Passing grid data to bootstrap modal without AJAX?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I've seen multiple pages regarding my issue. The closest I found was this:

[Passing data to a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal)

But I think my issue is slightly different.  I have pulled MySQL data and displayed it within a table via PHP.  I need to pull the row data via href into a bootstrap modal page.

On my edit.php page, here is the first line of the returned data, where the EDIT button and href is located:

```
 echo "<tr><td><a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-mini\" data-toggle=\"modal\"   href=\"#myEditModal\" data-project-id=\"$Row[pk_tId]\">Delete/Edit</a></td>";
```

Please disregard the lack of closing tags. It's in the code, just not displayed here.

I'm guessing I need to get `$Row[pk_tId]` and pass that into the modal, and then run a MySQL statement off pk_tId so that I can pull the data into the modal input fields.  My question is:  How do I do that?  I would like to just use javascript.  No ajax for now.  I'll learn that later.

So please, how do I get `$Row[pk_tId]` into the modal shown here:

```
 <div class="modal hide fade" id="myEditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelleby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <form class="well-small" action="edit.php" method="POST" id="modalForm" name="modalForm">
 <?php
    if (isset($_GET['pk_tId'])){
        $id = $_GET['pk_tId'];
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE pk_tId ='" .$id. "'");
        $selection = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    }
?>
         <label>Group</label>
    <input type="text" id="group" name="group" value="<?php echo $selection[mygroup]; ?>" />
```

Please disregard the closing form tags. They are there. I just didn't want to display a lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: I did answer but thinking better, I have to ask: the modal is a form submission? I mean, there is a page reload? Or the modal is just a plain html content in this same page? Can't figure it out without seeing all the code.

Comment: Using the code you provided below, I need to pass the pk_tId, which is a column in the actual database. Where you put this:

     data-project-id=\"".$_GET['id']."\"

How do I get this in there:

     $Row[pk_tId];

I tried this:  data-project-id=\"$Row[pk_tId]\" but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

How about passing it as a `$_GET` parameter?

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['pk_tId'])){
        $id = $_GET['pk_tId'];
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE pk_tId ='" .$id. "'");
        $selection = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    }
?>
<form class="well-small" action="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>" method="POST" id="modalForm" name="modalForm">
```

Then your first line of edit.php would be:

```
echo "<tr><td><a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-mini\" data-toggle=\"modal\"   href=\"#myEditModal\" data-project-id=\"".$_GET['id']."\">Delete/Edit</a></td>";
```