# Passing data to Bootstrap 3 Modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table with a bunch of data, and I've placed a button at the end of each row that I want to use to trigger a modal and pass the unique id of that row into the modal.

I found this answer: [Passing data to a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal)

But it doesn't appear to work with Bootstrap 3, and I can't find any data about this anywhere any ideas?

I'm using the same code listed:

Header:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href = "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
<link href = "bootstrap/css/styles.css" rel = "stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
$(".modal-body #bookId").val(myBookId);
});
</script>
</head>
```

Body:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="ISBN" title="Add this item" class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-primary" href="#addBookDialog">test</a>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="addBookDialog">
<div class="modal-header">
<button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
<h3>Modal header</h3>

</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>some content</p>
<input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value="" />
</div>
</div>
```

The resulting page will open the modal, but the text field is blank.

I forgot to mention, I do have both jquery and bootstrap loaded:

```
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: You seem to be doing it right. To be absolutely sure, try `console.log`-ing both `myBookId` and `$(".modal-body #bookId")`. Do they contain what they should?

Comment: I'm getting a Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined which is referring to the line  $(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {

Comment: if `$` is not defined, then you haven't loaded jQuery onto the page yet. You'll need both jQuery and bootstrap's JS.

Comment: I have loaded jQuery, I even moved the scripts up into the header to see if that would solve it, but it didn't change anything :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try manually triggering the modal, rather than using the data API.

Update the hyperlink like so:

```
<a data-id="ISBN" title="Add this item" class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-primary" href="#addBookDialog">test</a>
```

Then adjust your jQuery code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var _self = $(this);

    var myBookId = _self.data('id');
    $("#bookId").val(myBookId);

    $(_self.attr('href')).modal('show');
});
```

Seems to work for me; **jsFiddle** @ http://jsfiddle.net/4XJ54/

Comment: Thank you for this, your code helped me pinpoint the error, it was user error sadly.

Comment: without data-toggle="modal" its not working and data cannot pass to modal.

Comment: @PareshGami Is that meant to be a question, or are you saying this doesn't work? If it's the latter, the included jsFiddle would tend to disagree.