# How can I change the heading of the modal depending on the selected option

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

working off this question: [Passing data to Bootstrap 3 Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723111/passing-data-to-bootstrap-3-modal)

In all these examples, the data-id is sent to a text box, with this line:

```
<input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value="" />
```

How do I send the data (may be as a variable) so I can make it the heading of the modal instead of using an input type.
I tried something like this, but it does not work:

```
<p type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value="" />
```

For example, in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4XJ54/

the data-id "ISBN" is populated in the text box.
How do I get the data-id "ISBN" to show up as the heading instead?

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: `<p>` does not have  `value` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Use `text()` function. `.val()` is for inputs and `<p>` does not support value.

```
$("#bookId").text(myBookId); // for <p>
$("h4.modal-title").text(myBookId);// for Modal title
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4XJ54/267/)**

Comment: If I need to use this value to query a database, I can store it to a value in jquery and use the same variable in php correct?

Comment: Yes you can store it in a variable. And pass to php by using ajax

Comment: Is there a better way of getting it into a php  variable? I find using ajax very confusing. I was reading about using the data-id attribute, can this be applied here?

Comment: data-id does not related to server side. It is just a html storage. You have to use form actions or ajax

Comment: @user2883071 more people will respond to your other questions and help you if you start accepting some answers to your previous questions, like this one