# Pulling edited text from summernote textarea

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, summernote

I have a list of canned emails in a database. "Thanks for becoming a member", "Thank you for your purchase its on the way" - stuff like that. I am using Bootstrap modals to edit these emails. When I click the edit button, the modal drops down, and is populated with the data from the database: email name, subject, body. I am using [Passing data to a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal) to accomplish this. Works great. Now I am using summernote as my rich text editor.

Here is my textarea that displays the unedited data:

```
<textarea class="summernote input-block-level" id="content" name="content" rows="18"></textarea>
```

The class summernote is how the data gets directed to the output text area so it can be edited. Once the data has been edited, I click submit, and the data should be pulled to the JavaScript with the code below.

```
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
          $('button[id=editEmail]').on('click', function()
          {

var $email_edbody_array = $('textarea[name="content"]').html($('#summernote').code());
var $email_edbody = $email_edbody_array.html();
console.log("edited email" + $email_edbody);
```

The fun part is that this works fine IF the summernote text area is blank - as in if I am creating a new email instead of editing one.
The `console.log` should output the edited email body, but it does not. It outputs the original email body. I am not sure why.

What am I missing to get the edited email into my JavaScript. Below is the main parts of the code that I think matter for this question.

This section is the ouput to the page, and the data redirection for the edit button.

```
          <?php while ($datarow_emails = pg_fetch_assoc($results_emails))
          {
           echo " 
            <tr>
                <td>".$datarow_emails['internal_name']."</td> 
                <td>".$datarow_emails['email_subject']."</td>
                <td>".$datarow_emails['type']."</td>
                <td>
                        <span class='btn btn-info btn-small open-editEmailModal' data-toggle='modal' 
                            href='#editEmail' data-inm='".$datarow_emails['internal_name']."'
                            data-es='".$datarow_emails['email_subject']."'
                            data-bdy='".$datarow_emails['email_body']."'
                            data-ty=".$datarow_emails['type']."
                            data-ces=".$datarow_emails['canned_email_sid'].">
                        <i class='icon-edit icon-white'></i> Edit</span>

                        <span class='btn btn-danger btn-small open-delEmailModal' data-toggle='modal'href='#deleteWarning' data-ces=".$datarow_emails['canned_email_sid'].">
                        <i class='icon-remove icon-white'></i> Delete</span>
                </td>
            </tr>";
          } 
          ?>
```

This next part is the jQuery that redirects the data to the modal. The `.note-editable` is what redirects the email body.

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".open-editEmailModal", function()
{
  var internalName = $(this).data('inm');
  var emailSubject = $(this).data('es');
  var emailBody = $(this).data('bdy');
  var type = $(this).data('ty');
  var cannedEmSid = $(this).data('ces');

  $(".modal-body #canEmSid").val(cannedEmSid);
  $(".modal-body #interName").val(internalName);
  $(".modal-body #emailSub").val(emailSubject);
  $(".modal-body #emailBdy").val(emailBody);
  $(".modal-body .note-editable").html(emailBody);
  $(".modal-body #tYpe").val(type);
});
</script>
```

And here is the modal:

```
        <div id="editEmail" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="emailActivityLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel">Edit Canned Response</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="control-group" style="margin-bottom:8px;">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputInternalName">Internal Name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" id="interName" name="interName" placeholder="Internal Name" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="canEmSid" name="canEmSid"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group" style="margin-bottom:8px;">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputInternalName">Type</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                  <select id="tYpe" name="tYpe">
                    <?php

                    while ($datearow_typeDD2 = pg_fetch_assoc($results_typesDD2))
                    {
                    echo "<option value='".$datearow_typeDD2['buyer_seller_sid']."'>".$datearow_typeDD2['buyer_seller_type']."</option>\n";
                    }
                    ?>
                  </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group" style="margin-bottom:8px;">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputSubject">Email Subject</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" id="emailSub" name="emailSub" placeholder="Email Subject">
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </form>
                        <!-- <div class="text-editor"></div> -->
                    <!-- <div  class="summernote"></div> -->
                <div id="emailEditor">
                    <div class="controls">
                    <textarea class="summernote input-block-level" id="content" name="content" rows="18"></textarea>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success" id="editEmail">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $('.summernote').summernote({  
    });

          $('button[id=editEmail]').on('click', function()
          {

var $email_edbody_array = $('textarea[name="content"]').html($('#summernote').code());
var $email_edbody = $email_edbody_array.html();
```

Below this is just other variables and the AJAX script.

Comment: Did you find the answer? I'm looking for a way to send Summernote's edited text via ajax but I don't know how to find the text.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

TomPHP solution does not work with the newer version of summernote.
In case anyone stumbles upon this post here is a current solution.

```
var textareaValue = $('#summernote').summernote('code');
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this!

Answer (score 32):

Instead of Getting the value of the Field You can use the summernote `code()` Function.

```
var textareaValue = $("#summernote").code();
```

For Your Code:

```
var textareaValue = $("#content").code();
```

Answer (score 8):

- Before version 0.7.0:

```
$('#summernote').code()
```

- Version 0.7.0 and above:

```
$('#summernote').summernote('code')
```

Comment: Thanks - could not understand WHY it would not work until I ran across this little post.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of Summernote objects, then you can use this script to auto-create "hidden" input elements in a form and update summernote value to each of them. This works great for my needs.

```
$(function(){

        // Reference each summernote object
        var summernoteObjects = [
            'summernote_id1',
            'summernote_id2',
            'summernote_id3',
            'summernote_id4',
            'summernote_id5',
            'summernote_id6',
            'summernote_id7',
            'summernote_id8',
        ];

        // Create hidden values for each summernote
        for(var i=0; i<summernoteObjects.length; i++){
            var objectPointerName = summernoteObjects[i];

            $("#" + objectPointerName).summernote();
            $("#formId").append("<input type='hidden' name='"+objectPointerName+"'>");
        }

        // Update hidden values on form submit
        $("#formId").submit(function(){
            for(var i=0; i<summernoteObjects.length; i++){
                var objectPointerName = summernoteObjects[i];
                var summernoteValue = $("#" + objectPointerName).summernote('code');

                $("#formId input[name='"+objectPointerName+"']").val(summernoteValue);
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Why are you creating elements? Summernote, if initialized correctly will hide the associated input. A class selector or summernote would work a treat

Answer (score 1):

Use like this
$('.summernote').summernote('code')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone struggles to set data from Ajax in summernote like I did.

Please note that **note** from 'data.note' below is the column from the DB

```
$.ajax({success: function(replied){data = JSON.parse(replied);$('#yourSummerID').summernote('code', data.note);}});
```