# how to get input value from summornote text Editor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, summernote

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvWXu.png)

//html code
//<div id="txtDescription" class="summernote datarequired" //title="Description Reuired">

// jquery code for get data
i use $('#txtDescription').val() to access value But not getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to `$("#txtDescription").code()` or `$("#txtDescription").summernote('code')` either of this might help you solve your problem.

please refer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921976/pulling-edited-text-from-summernote-textarea)

for further info.

Comment: thanks prabin gautam,
//$("#txtDescription").summernote('code') 
helpfull

Answer (score 0):

div elements don't have value. input elements have it.
In case of div you might use

```
document.getElementById("txtDescription").innerHTML
```

or

```
document.getElementById("txtDescription").innerText
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to use this when the page is loaded, or in an onload event.

```
 document.querySelector('#txtDescription').innerHTML

   or

 document.querySelector('#txtDescription').innerText
```