# Passing specific value to modal from dynamic buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a few different modals on my page that need data passed into them. I solved that problem with [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal), which has me using jQuery now and was really helpful. This is what I have now:

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit", function () {
    $(".modal-body #value").val($('.edit').data('id'));
});
```

My problem is that since my page has dynamically created buttons (from a foreach based on the model), no matter which button I click, this gets the value from the first button.  How do I instead get the value from the button that was clicked.

I thought about giving them all separate ids, but I don't want to make a function for each id. I read that there is a data property to this .on method, but I can't find a good example of how to use it and if it would work in my case.

If anyone has any suggestions I would be very grateful. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit", function () {
    // Use $(this) to reference the clicked button
    $(".modal-body #value").val($(this).data('id')); 
});
```

Comment: oh wow I can't believe it was that easy. I always forget about the magical `this` word. I'll accept this soon as I can in 10 minutes!

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the button being clicked by using the `this` keyword. Try the following:

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit", function () {
    $(".modal-body #value").val($(this).data('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap's events:

```
$('#your-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var btn = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var id = btn.data('id');
    $("#value").val(id);
});
```

See the "Events" section of http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals :

> [The `show.bs.modal` event] fires immediately when the `show` instance method is called. If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the `relatedTarget` property of the event.