# Create dynamic buttons in bootstrap modal, like jQuery UI

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can I create bootstrap buttons on the fly using the javascript?

for example in jQuery UI, you can do something like this:

```
JQ("#dialog_component").dialog({
    bgiframe: true,
    draggable:  false,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    show: 'fade',
    position:  'top',
    hide: 'fade',
    width:  500,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: btns,  // these would be the translated buttons

});
```

I want to pass this `btns` variable as `buttons` in a bootstrap `modal`, like I do in jQuery UI. But from the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) it seems there isn't something like that. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I would look at [Bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com) or [Bootstrap3-Dialog](http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/) to make life easy....

Comment: It's pretty straightforward to implement this yourself with a little JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing specific value to modal from dynamic buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124408/passing-specific-value-to-modal-from-dynamic-buttons)

Answer (score 0):

[BootBox](http://bootboxjs.com) does this for you, and has [`buttons` option](http://bootboxjs.com/#gist6327301).