# Passing data-id to ColdFusion Query within (bootstrap) modal body

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, coldfusion

I'm using the method already laid out in this thread:

[Passing data to a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal)

It works spot on. I am able to pass data to the modal and display it in a field within a form. The question is: what's the easiest way to use that data in a ColdFusion query within the modal body?

**Modal Button:**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="495.00" title="View Dates" class="open-registerModal btn btn-primary" href="#registerModal">test</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", ".open-registerModal", function () {
     var myPrice = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal-body #price").val( myPrice );
});
</script>
```

**Modal Body Query**

```
<cfquery name="getdata" datasource="thedatabase">
   SELECT * 
   FROM Table 
   WHERE cost = (PRICE FROM ABOVE)
</cfquery>
```

I would really like to use the same modal for all of the buttons on my page and just change out the data-id on each individual button. Any suggestions?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad

"what's the easiest way to use that data in a ColdFusion query within the modal body?"

"Any suggestions?"

Answer (score 2):

The general idea is to do a POST through ajax.  Collect the data you want to post use via `.data()` and then post to a `.cfm` or `.cfc?method=foo` and the values will arrive in the `FORM` scope or function's arguments in CF respectively.

Comment: Any examples that you could quickly give me?

Comment: break it down, and ask google, if you can't find the answer, ask here.