# Passing many data to bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am working in a binary tree where box A has two legs : box B as LEFT, and box C as RIGHT (both still empty). For new registration, user can click box B or C as.

The link embedded is :

```
<a data-toggle='modal' href=\"index.php?page=new-member&upline=$uplineid&position=$position#modal-register\">
```

How to pass the `uplineid` and position when `#modal-register` is open?

Comment: @Dan Txs for editing my question. Still don't get the answer. Maybe I need to use another method.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking, but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal