# Passing Element Data to a Bootdtrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Having a frustrating time, made even worse that the examples I see everywhere are not working in this instance. My assumption is because I am not understanding what elements are being loaded in which order.

The question is common enough, I have a button that I want to pass data from into the modal it opens. Let's say I want to pass in the id. My first idea was something like this which is the typical answer on Stack Overflow:

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="product-button">Product Name</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#product-button').click(function() {
        var productId = $(this).attr('name');
        $(".modal-body #testContainer").val(productId);
    });
});
```

This is seen here:
[Passing data to a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal)

However, this appears not to work for me. The kicker for my scenario is that the buttons are generated dynamically and I am wondering if because I've wrapped everything in a helper function and it ties itself to the page before the dynamic buttons are created and therefore doesn't know they exist and to listen for a .click event (they are created through a search, the buttons are the results of the search)

Anybody have any ideas on how I can go about passing data to a modal with this limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the buttons are generated dynamically, you have to use [**event-delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to make it work:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#product-button',function() {
        var productId = $(this).attr('name');
        $(".modal-body #testContainer").val(productId);
    });
});
```

### Event Delegation:

> > Event delegation refers to the process of using event propagation (bubbling) to handle events at a higher level in the DOM than the element on which the event originated. It allows us to attach a single event listener for elements that exist now or in the future.

Comment: It took me a bit to get this fixed, so appologies int eh dealy in selecting your answer, but the reading up on event-delegation was exactly what I needed. Thanks for that.