# Passing PHP variable to modal Window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am following the solution given at [Pass PHP variable to bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693863/pass-php-variable-to-bootstrap-modal)

In my case, the trigger link passes the right value to the AJAX method, I have ckecked it in the developer consoler from the browser:

```
<td><a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-default btn-small" id="custId" data-toggle="modal" data-id="8">Edit</a></td>
```

Then, the modal windows opens, but the test value from info-doctor.php is not shown in it, not the test value and not the text "NO DATA".

What is wrong in my implementation?

Here you have my code:

Trigger:

```
$mostrar = '<td><a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-default btn-small" id="custId" data-toggle="modal" data-id="'.$row['id_doctor'].'">Edit</a></td>';
```

JS:

```
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var rowid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        console.log(rowid)
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url : 'info-doctor.php', //Here you will fetch records 
            data :  'rowid='+ rowid, //Pass $id
            success : function(data){
            $('.fetched-data').html(data);//Show fetched data from database
            }
        });
     });
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if($_POST['rowid']) {
    $id = $_POST['rowid']; //escape string

 }
 else {
     echo "NO DATA";
 }
?>
```

EDIT

This is the complete JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >


            $(document).ready(function(){


        $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var rowid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');

        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url : 'info-doctor.php', //Here you will fetch records 
            data :  'rowid='+ rowid, //Pass $id
            success : function(data){
            $('.fetched-data').html(data);//Show fetched data from database
            console.log(rowid)
            }
        });
     });
       var dataTable =  $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,

                ajax: "employee-grid-data.php", // json datasource
                 //send it through get method

                language: {
        processing:     "Procesando datos...",
        search:         "Buscar:",
        lengthMenu:    "Mostrar _MENU_ doctores/as",
        info:           "Mostrando del doctor/a _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ doctores/as seleccionados" ,
        infoEmpty:      "Mostrando doctor/a 0 al 0 de un total de 0 doctores/as",
        infoFiltered:   "(filtrados de _MAX_ doctores/as)",
        infoPostFix:    "",
        loadingRecords: "Procesando datos...",
        zeroRecords:    "No hay doctores/as que cumplan los criterios",
        emptyTable:     "Noy hay datos que cumplan los criterios",
        paginate: {
            first:      "Primero",
            previous:   "Anterior",
            next:       "Siguiente",
            last:       "Ultimo"
        },
        aria: {
            sortAscending:  ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre croissant",
            sortDescending: ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre décroissant"
        }
    }

                } );

               var colvis = new $.fn.dataTable.ColVis( dataTable, {
                    buttonText: '<img src="images/down.gif" >',
                    activate: 'mouseover',
                    exclude: [ 0 ]  
                   } );
               $( colvis.button() ).prependTo('th:nth-child(1)');



            } );
        </script>
```

And this is the complete PHP for testing the issue:

```
<?php

     echo "NO DATA";

?>
```

Comment: Well, you're not echoing anything back at all, unless the `rowid` param is missing, which it's not ?

Comment: @adeneo, you are right, but I have checked it also without if clause and only echo "TEST" inside the PHP  file, and the same result, thank, you

Comment: So if your PHP is just `echo "something";` and you do `console.log(data)` in the success function, you get nothing ?

Comment: @adeneo, I am getting nothing

Comment: If you visit the URL direcly in the browser, i.e. typing `localhost://info-doctor.php` or whatever in the adressbar, and you still get nothing, something is wrong with your PHP. If you do get something, the problem is the ajax call

Comment: @adeneo, I have edited my question and included the complete JS, so you can check if there is something that could interfere the execution. And I have also included the test version of the PHP file and the modal window output

Comment: @adeneo, the PHP direct execution shows NO DATA as result, it works, please take a look http://herasalud.com/info-doctor.php

Comment: `console.log(data)` in the success function, not the `rowid` and see that there is no data returned. Did you see the `rowid` in the console by the way, if you didn't, the function never runs, probably because `show.bs.modal` never happens

Comment: @adeneo, I don't see the rowid in the console, but the modal window opens

Comment: Try this and see what the console says -> https://jsfiddle.net/ctyzmcaj/1/

Comment: What everyone is commenting about and appears to not be understood is...... because the ajax is calling HTML in the success function, the **PHP file needs to echo or return the HTML you wish to display in the modal window**, not simply a variable setting. Also, if the variable is set on the page (before modal) you don't need ajax to pass that variable to the modal.

Comment: @adeneo, the console output is empty on that point or  I can't find it. May be you need the URL from the web site and check the console?

Comment: So you've copied the code from the fiddle, and got no console logs at all ?

Comment: @adeneo, you are right. No console logs or not found them

Comment: I think you should not use "show.bs.modal" event. This make modal shows before loading data because of async ajax. You can fire up modal after done loading it's content

Answer (score 1):

You don't need AJAX to pass a variable if it is already set on the primary page especially if it's already a data attribute on the link. Use the data attribute on the modal link:

```
<a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-default btn-small" id="custId" data-toggle="modal" data-id="'.$row['id_doctor'].'">Edit</a>
```

Specifically, you have it available via `data-id="'.$row['id_doctor'].'"`

So....

```
   $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
       var rowid = $(this).attr('data-id');
        /*
        proceed with rest of modal using the rowid variable as necessary 
        */
     });
```

OR

```
     $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
       var rowid = $('#custId').attr('data-id');

     /*
       (This may need better targeting than an id which appear as though it would repeat resulting in invalid markup.) 
       proceed with rest of modal using the rowid variable as necessary 
     */
     });
```

Comment: I need to get values from a MySQL database, that is the reason for calling the AJAX method to pass the variable to the PHP file.

Comment: My point is, you *already* have the variable information in the primary page.. you *don't* need to query the database to retrieve it again. You merely need to pass the variable to the modal call.

Comment: I understand that you say that the variable is already in the primary page, and then can you tell me how can I get the data there from the database? Just a simple PHP script with a query to the database? How can I pass the given variable to the modal call?