# passing value from php to modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying learn to pass a value from a php to modal but it does not seems to work, there are no errors in console.

this is my php inside a while loop

```
echo'
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>'.$row->equipID.'</td>
      <td>'.$row->equipType.'</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#editModal" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-id="'.$row->equipID.'" data-toggle="modal">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>';
```

this is the html file where i want to pass the value from the php

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h3 class="modal-title">Edit Truck Category</h3>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class = "fetched-data"></div>
          <input type="text" id="truck" placeholder="Truck Category *"  required>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is my js

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#editModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var rowid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url : 'fetch_record.php', //Here you will fetch records
            data :  'rowid='+ rowid, //Pass $id
            success : function(data){
            $('.fetched-data').html(data);//Show fetched data from database
            }
        });
     });
  });
</script>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Did you print the php output in log file or directly in browser(without using ajax) and verify whether you get the valid html output code from php?

Comment: console.log(data) inside success and see if it's what you expect.

Comment: there's no value.

i also tried to put alert('success'); inside success but it doesn't popping out so i can't verify if the data passed from php is correct

Comment: @NoobProgramer check first your fetch_record.php if its returning the data

Comment: yes, i tried to put a dummy data and it work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass PHP variable to bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693863/pass-php-variable-to-bootstrap-modal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to include

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use **load** function to implement the above functionality. I will describe it by using an example. Please note I have only included the code segments which are required to explain.

**1.I am returning a table from the PHP file (assume: file name- data.php).**

```
$table = "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
// Table data
$table.="</table>";
echo $table;
```

**2.Modal to show the data.**

```
<div id="mymodal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body mymodal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**3.Load data to the modal body**

```
$('.mymodal-body').load('/data.php', function (result) {
        $('#mymodal').modal({show: true});
```

I wish the above code samples will help you get an idea for your issue. You may give a try using the load function.