# set a php value to be inserted in href as a get parameter on click of a link

Tags: php, html

```
<li><a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-code="<?php echo "carrer"?>">Career</a></li>
```

suppose this  is a link and I want to send the echoed value carrer to.....

```
<a class="text_center sign" title="one" href="rashu.php?test=axis"><img class="sign img-circle" src="images/icon/belier.png" alt=""><br>Axis</a>
```

career should be as after `test=axis?carrer=<that echoed value.....>`

Comment: you need to use `data-code="carrer"`

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes.

1. echo a static string `carrer` which is not need to do.
2. use `"` inside `"`, which is invalid.

Change

`data-code="<?php echo "carrer"?>"`

to

`data-code="carrer"` **or** `data-code="<?php echo 'carrer'?>"`

***Main problem Solution:***

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/t71wqat6/)

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    var modal_class = $(".modal_class").attr('data-code');
    var sign = $(".sign").attr("href");

  $(".sign").attr("href", sign+"&test_carrer="+modal_class);
  alert($(".sign").attr("href"));
})
```

Comment: Sir, I know i am wrong at it tell me how I can do it correctly......would be a great favour of you........

Comment: Little confusing, You need something echo in the `carrer`. But what is the string?? Is it `<a class="text_center sign" title="one" href="rashu.php?test=axis"><img class="sign img-circle" src="images/icon/belier.png" alt=""><br>Axis</a>`??

Comment: Is this possible or not..........to send a value of this data-code to the other llink..

Comment: make other link a sting like `$carrer = '<a href="">Link</a>';` and echo it in `data-code="<?php echo $carrer;?>"`

Comment: I think u took my question a bit wrong.....I want to send this data-code value to other link as a request parameter..........

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027186/php-how-to-put-and-passing-variable-in-modal-url

Comment: sir, I just want to send this data-code value to the request parameter of a link inside modal(bootstrap), that opens on click of the link disscussed first.......

Comment: but sir it is adding same carrer in each link........in request parameter as test_carreer=carrer for all the other lnks........

Comment: Sir, pardon me, i can;t help you, sorry.

Comment: How can i know you have 100 link or 100000 links???? it is not my business, if you make a question such a way than you can't get that much trouble.

Comment: we are here to help each other out....you are getting annoyed......nevertheless thanku for helping out........

Comment: Your question is not too clear as i said earlier, I am annoyed because of my time.