# Pass PHP variable to modal

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql data which I call to display to my PHP table and then for example I clicked the username01, I wanted to call the other columns of that username01 (e.g. password01, id01) to display to my modal fields.
Here's my code:

PHP

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" ?> <a href="#?<?php echo $row['id']; $id; ?>" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;"> <?php echo "<font color='blue'>" . $row['ipaddress'] . "</font></a></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
```

Modal

```
<?php
include 'includes\dbconn.php';
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from devopstbl where id=$id");
$ipaddress = $row['ipaddress'];
$name = $row['name'];
$department = $row['department'];

?>
<div id="id01" class="modal">

  <form class="modal-content animate" method="GET" action="ipaddress.php">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Exit">&times;</span>
      <img src="images/avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <label for="ipaddress"><b>Username <?php echo $username; ?></b></label>
      <input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+" name="username" value="<?php echo $ipaddress; ?>" required>
```

Apparently.. the $id only gets the id01 even i clicked the other data like id02 etc. and does not get its other columns like username01 password01..
Am i missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP : How to put and pass variable in modal URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027186/php-how-to-put-and-pass-variable-in-modal-url)

Comment: I'd like to see some better security practices on that query for sure.   Prepared statements.

Comment: Terrible HTML syntax. `<font>` tag is deprecated, and do not use `onclick` on `<a>` tag. For `<img>` tag, you missed `alt` attribute. And for the PHP code, where does the `$id` come from? Also, don't use `include`, use `require_once()` instead. Also it should be `includes/dbconn.php`. For the modal, the variable `$row` is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Put yout Modal-part to while loop.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $id = $row['id'];
  $username = $row['username'];
  $ipaddress = $row['ipaddress'];
  $name = $row['name'];

  echo '<tr>
    <td>
       <a href="#?'.$id.'" onclick="document.getElementById(\'id'.$id.'\').style.display=\'block\'" style="width:auto;"><font color="blue">'.$ipaddress.'</font></a>

       <div id="id'.$id.'" class="modal">
         <form class="modal-content animate" method="GET" action="ipaddress.php">
           <div class="imgcontainer">
             <span onclick="document.getElementById(\'id'.$id.'\').style.display=\'none\'" class="close" title="Exit">&times;</span>
             <img src="images/avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
           </div>
           <div class="container">
             <label for="ipaddress"><b>Username '.$username.'</b></label> 
             <input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+" name="username" value="'.$ipaddress.'" required>
           </div>
         </form>
       </div>

    </td>
    <td>'.$name.'</td>
  ';           
}
```