# Woocommerce single product show in modal Bootstrap

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, woocommerce

I am designing a WooCommerce theme and I need to know how I can show single -product into a modal Bootstrap 3 and no display on a single page .
How I can fix this?
This is an example :

http://demos.jckemp.com/woocommerce-quickview/

Answer (score 0):

I would buy one of the plugins / extensions in the link you provided or even one I found on Woocommerce page: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-quick-view/

This will add out-of-the-box support to what you want to achieve, will be simpler and faster.

If you don't want to buy it, the process behind might be tricky, as you need to pass the ID of the product to the modal and then trigger the Woocommerce shortcode:

You can take a look on how to pass the data here: [Passing data to a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal)

And then, inside the modal you load the product id, like they explain in their [Shortcodes page](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/):

> Clicking this option will place this shortcode into your editor:
>   [product id="" sku=""]. This is fairly self explanitory and will
>   display a singular product with specific id or SKU, e.g.
>
> [product id="97"]
>
> [product sku="CLUBM"]