# Bootsrap - how to set the title and content dynamically

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to show a `bootstrap` modal for my app. In which I would like to pass the `size`, `title` and `content` parameters. so using a single modal i can use multiple requirement.

with all above information i would like to pass the default `options` too.

at present i do like this:

```
var options = {
    "backdrop" : "static",
    "keyboard" : false,
    "show" : false
}

$('#basicModal').modal(options);
```

How can i extend this in to my requirement using the `bootstrap` inbuild/custom functions?

Any one help me please?

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xxydbb3g/)

**Update**

I find a way to pass params, how it works?

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Modal-Dialog-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-3-Bootstrap-3-Dialog/examples/#available-options

Comment: Check this link may helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/dwojLdjk/5/

```
var options = {
    "backdrop" : "static",
    "keyboard" : false,
    "show" : true
}

$('#showModal').click(function() {
    $("#resultFormModal").find("h4.modal-title").html('new title');
    $("#resultFormModal").find("div.modal-body").html('new message');
    $("#resultFormModal").modal(options);
});
```

Comment: Ok, But here i find some other way, http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Modal-Dialog-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-3-Bootstrap-3-Dialog/examples/#available-options

Comment: @3gwebtrain Ok, do as you see fit. But your solution required include additional plugin, for what ? if you can do it with `jquery`

Comment: I tried with is, i am getting error: `$('#basicModal').modal();
   $('#basicModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
       alert('Modal is successfully shown!');
   });`

Comment: error: `Unexpected identifier` - why any thing wrong?

Comment: @3gwebtrain can you create `jsfiddle` with your error?

Comment: @3gwebtrain you call modal after create page, you need call it with on click your button, remove `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal"` from your button, and delegate event on click button, look at my `jsfiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/dwojLdjk/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can set header like this

```
$('#myModalLabel').html('New Header');
```

and for body

```
$('.modal-body').html('<h1>New Body</h1>');
```

Below is fiddle demo.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxydbb3g/1/)