# passing a php variable dynamically to a bootstrap modal

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a php loop that writes hundrends of records, I need to have a button on each line to trigger a bootstrap modal that will allow to edit this specific record. can't really sent the line ID (it's a user ID) via GET since the URL doesn't change, or by POST since the page doesn't refresh ... I tried with AJAX but could seem to figure it out.

in my file the php variable is $userID= some number; ... which changes at every line

so every line refers to the same modal in which i added a data-id (or is there any other way to pass tha value to my modal?)

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success"
data-toggle="modal"
data-target="#editUser"
id="theuser"
data-id="<?php echo $userID;?>"> 
Update
</a>
```

How can I retrieve $userId in the modal so I can do an Mysql query on it ? (i understand there is a seperation between the server side aspect of php and the fact the data-id is only browser based ... but there must be a way to generate dynamically content using php for a modal ?

thanks in advance!

Comment: read on this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal

Answer (score 1):

You can send user_id as param in URL `<a href="/your_route?user_id_for_query=<?php echo $userID;?>" specify_method>` and than in your action for that route you could access it as `GET` or `POST` param.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to access it through jQuery and then run an ajax request to a php file that would run your sql query.

```
var userID = jQuery('#theuser').data('id');
```

The above fetches the data attribute `data-id` which will allow you to use it in an ajax request.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "yourscript.php",
    data: {userID: userID},
    timeout: 30000,
    datatype: 'json'
}).success(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

---

You're absolutely right about the server and client being separate. You need to parse the client side data back to the server to be processed as you require.

Comment: I think i get it but not sure about the where i need to put all this. the modal needs to bring up a form prefilled with data so we can edit a user credentials.  assuming my base file is index.php , where would i put this code ?  inside the modal ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
You can get the value of user_id from the given code

```
var userID = $('#theuser').attr('data-id');
```

the pass the userID IN AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "yourscript.php",
    data: {userID: userID},
    timeout: 30000,
    datatype: 'json'
}).success(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

i think it will meet your needs.
Thank You

Comment: use it on onclick then u can get dynamic for each row.

Comment: where should these 2 block of codes reside, if the file anywhere or within the modal ?

Comment: in u ".js" or ur "wiew file" file in which u using to do the ajax call