# How to open a bootstrap modal when checked a chec-box (when a tick is placed on a check box)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, modal-dialog

I've a custom checkbox.
What I want is to to open a bootstrap modal when the checkbox is checked.
I want a bootstrap modal to open just as when clicked a button.
Hope you understood my question.
How can I do it.

### HTML CODE

```css
/*
          ----------------------------------------------
                              CHECKBOX
          ----------------------------------------------
*/


/* Base for label styling */

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* checkbox aspect */

[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  //border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: #09ad7e;
  border-radius: 3px;
  //box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3)
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  //border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 3px;
  //box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3)
}


/* checked mark aspect */

[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  content: '✔';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #f8f8f8;
  transition: all .2s;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label:after {
  content: '✔';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ddd;
  transition: all .2s;
}


/* checked mark aspect changes */

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}


/* disabled checkbox */

[type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked)+label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked+label:before {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #bbb;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked+label:after {
  color: #999;
}

[type="checkbox"]:disabled+label {
  color: #aaa;
}


/* accessibility */

[type="checkbox"]:checked:focus+label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked):focus+label:before {
  outline: none !important;
}


/* hover style just for information */

label:hover:before {
  //border: 1px solid #4778d9!important;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label {
  color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="test7" checked="checked" />
<label for="test7">Custom Avalability</label>
<br /><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="test6" />
<label for="test6">Manual</label>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check if input is checked on change of `input[type="checkbox"]` and show the modal.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e){
   if(e.target.checked){
     $('#myModal').modal();
   }
});
```

```css
      /*
      ----------------------------------------------
                          CHECKBOX
      ----------------------------------------------
      */
      /* Base for label styling */
      [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
      [type="checkbox"]:checked {
        position: absolute;
        left: -9999px;
      }
      [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
      [type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 25px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      /* checkbox aspect */

      [type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left:0; top: 0px;
        width: 20px; height: 20px;
        //border: 1px solid #aaa;
        background: #09ad7e;
        border-radius: 3px;
        //box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3)
      }
      [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before {
      content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left:0; top: 0px;
        width: 20px; height: 20px;
        //border: 1px solid #fff;
        background: #eee;
        border-radius: 3px;
        //box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3)
      }
      /* checked mark aspect */

      [type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
        content: '✔';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; left: 4px;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #f8f8f8;
        transition: all .2s;
      }
      [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
      content: '✔';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; left: 4px;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #ddd;
        transition: all .2s;

      }
      /* checked mark aspect changes */
      [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
      }
      [type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
      }
      /* disabled checkbox */
      [type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before,
      [type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:before {
        box-shadow: none;
        border-color: #bbb;
        background-color: #ddd;
      }
      [type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:after {
        color: #999;
      }
      [type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
        color: #aaa;
      }
      /* accessibility */
      [type="checkbox"]:checked:focus + label:before,
      [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked):focus + label:before {
       outline: none !important;
      }

      /* hover style just for information */
      label:hover:before {
        //border: 1px solid #4778d9!important;
      }

      [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label {
      color: #ddd;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="test7" checked="checked"/>
<label for="test7">Custom Avalability</label>
<br /><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="test6"/>
<label for="test6">Manual</label>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Checkbox is checked
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the bad thing about this answer is that if you press cancel on the modal, the checkbox will be checked and not uncheck

Comment: @anpsmn how can i get the data value from checkbox in modal after opening it?

Comment: @RohitKishore try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25060114/473016)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the JS fiddle. let me know if you want anymore changes in it.

http://jsfiddle.net/k3aogpv0/5/

with simple custom data attribute:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="test7" checked="checked" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" />
```

OR with Javascript if you doesn't want on unchecked

```
 ​$("[id^=test]").on("change", function(e){
    if(e.target.checked){
    $('#myModal').modal();
  }
 });
```

Comment: I've already tried this but what I want is to open a modal only when checked not when unchecked. In this case the modal opens in both the trigger events.

Comment: You can check out the in the below answer. :)
Thanks for your try @zan :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="test7" checked="checked"/>
<label for="test7">Custom Avalability</label>
<br /><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="test6"/>
<label for="test6">Manual</label>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Checkbox is checked
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide some explanation as well please