# Get MySQL data to bootstrap model

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a list of users on my web page echoed using a PHP loop. The names are links look like this.

```
<a href="user.php?user={$user['id']}">{$user['username']}</a>
```

So, when I click on each user, I am taken to `user.php` page.

`user.php` displays each user's information based on the query parameter `$user['id']` in the URL. Using `$_GET['id']` method.

So, that's the current situation I have.

**What I now want to do is, display user's information in a** **Bootstrap Model**

So, how could I get that query parameter into the Bootstrap model. And do the same PHP processes to get the same functionality ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Bearing in mind the Bootstrap docs **has a section on exactly this scenario:** http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target

Comment: Thank you..!!! The documentation you mentioned was really helpful and I managed to do it. Thanks again!!!

Comment: I've been testing the model and it's working great.!!! Anyway, I'm little bit stuck in when trying to call a PHP function with the argument passed via `data-whatever` attribute.  I created the link like this. `<a href="#user"  data-toggle="modal"  data-id="{$user['id']}">Text</a>` And I can grab that value using **bind in** js. But, how can I use that value as an argument when calling a PHP function inside the model ?

Comment: That’s outside the scope of discussing in comments. Please ask another question if you have another query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [google](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&client=ubuntu#q=bootstrap+modal+get+data) this you can get number of results related to it.

Here is code seems to be referred from one of this question [passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal)

**HTML**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="ISBN564541" title="Add this item" class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-primary" href="#addBookDialog">test</a>

<div class="modal hide" id="addBookDialog">
 <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>some content</p>
        <input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".open-AddBookDialog").click(function () {
        $('#bookId').val($(this).data('id'));
        $('#addBookDialog').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: I've been testing the model and it's working great.!!! Anyway, I'm little bit stuck in when trying to call a PHP function with the argument passed via data-whatever attribute. I created the link like this. <a href="#user" data-toggle="modal" data-id="{$user['id']}">Text</a> And I can grab that value using bind in js. But, how can I use that value as an argument when calling a PHP function inside the model ?