# Confirmation Bootstrap modal using PHP&MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, bootstrap-modal

So, here is the deal. I have a PHP function which generates data from MySQL table and adds links for change of data and delte data from table/base.

It generates something like this
[image]

Basically, I want to call confirmation modal before deleting a row in a table. As PHP code for deleting data works nicely I thought that it would be nice to have some sort confirmation before deleting data

Something like this
[image]

So, I tried to create confirmation modal using resources from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831077/call-a-php-function-on-a-bootstrap-modal-using-ajax) but without any luck.

Here is a PHP code that is connecting to the MySQL db

```
    $db = connectPDO();

    $sql = 'SELECT * from drzava ORDER BY id ASC';

    $podaci = $db->query($sql);

    $nazivi_stupaca = array('ID', 'Oznaka','Naziv','Valuta');
    showHTMLTableWithEditDeleteLink($nazivi_stupaca, $podaci, 'drzava');

    closePDO($db);

} catch (PDOException $e) {

    showPDOErrors($e, $db);
}

// ===============here is HTML CODE for modal===========
?>
<div id="confirmModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Delete?</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Are you sure you wish to delete?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    <button onclick="ok_hit()" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Code for function **showHTMLTableWithEditDeleteLink** is here

```
function showHTMLTableWithEditDeleteLink($header_arr, $data_arr, $table_name) {
    echo '<div class="table-responsive">';
    echo '<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>Rbr.</th>';
    foreach($header_arr as $naziv_stupca) {
        echo '<th th style="text-align: center;">', $naziv_stupca, '</th>';
    }
    echo '<th style="text-align: center" colspan=2>Akcija</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</thead>';

    echo '<tbody>';
    $rbr = 1;
    foreach($data_arr as $polja) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td >", $rbr++, ".</td>";
            foreach ($polja as $pozicija => $vrijednost) {
                if( is_integer($pozicija) ) {
                    echo "<td >", $vrijednost, "</td>";
                }
            }

            echo "<td>";
            if(myAuth::checkRights('UPDATE')){

                echo '<a href="';
                echo $table_name.'_promjena.php';
                echo '?id=';
                echo $polja[0];     
                echo '"class="btn btn-success btn-xs" role="button" ';
                echo '"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Change</a>';

            }
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            if(myAuth::checkRights('DELETE')){
                // link for delete
                echo '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"';
                echo 'role="button" onclick="show_confirm()"';//calling modal before submiting
                echo 'href="';
                echo $table_name.'_brisanje.php';
                echo '?id=';
                echo $polja[0];     
                echo '"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>  Delete!</a>';
            }
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo '</tbody>';

    echo '</table>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

And here is my PHP delete part of the code

```
try {

        $sql = 'DELETE FROM drzava WHERE id = :id';

        $db = connectPDO();

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id);

        $id = (int)$_GET['id'];

        $stmt->execute();

        echo "Pobrisana kava za id: $id<br>";

        closePDO($db);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        showPDOErrors($e, $db, $stmt);
    }
```

And finally, here is script.js for modal id

```
// function : show_confirm()
function show_confirm(){
    // shows the modal on button press
    $('#confirmModal').modal('show');
}

// function : ok_hit()
function ok_hit(){
    // hides the modal
    $('#confirmModal').modal('hide');
    alert("OK Pressed");

    // all of the functions to do with the ok button being pressed would go in here
}
```

I'know that it's a bit long question, but I wanted to elaborate my problem as detailed as possible, because I'm having this problem for a months know and to  be fair PHP code worked nicely and I never really tried to do anything till recently, because I realized that I need some sort of confirmation for data removing in my future application. Thank you

Comment: Suing bootstrap.css? Can you be more specific please ?

Comment: Yes .Bootstrap.css

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982295/confirm-delete-modal-dialog-with-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: Ok, thank you but I somehow believe that in my case is not the issue Because I've added bootstrap.js and css links in my header/footer. If that's  what you meant

Comment: Thank you imran, that's good link for starters :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I' ve finally figure it out.  Using link that **imran** posted I've managed to successfully replicate and initiate on my application

In a part of the function where "delete" link is created if changed from this

```
            echo '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"';
            echo 'role="button" onclick="show_confirm()"';//calling modal before submiting
            echo 'href="';
            echo $table_name.'_brisanje.php';
            echo '?id=';
            echo $polja[0];     
            echo '"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>  Delete!</a>';
```

To this

```
            echo '<a href="#" ';
            echo 'data-href="';
            echo $table_name.'_brisanje.php';
            echo '?id=';
            echo $polja[0].'" ';
            echo 'data-toggle="modal"';
            echo 'data-target="#confirm-delete "';
            echo 'class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" role="button"  ';           
            echo '"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>  Izbriši</a>';
```

Next, on my js file, I 've added this

```
$('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
});
```

And finally on my connecting part of the code (that's where I'm connecting to MySQL, try/catch block-->see question and using **showHTMLTableWithEditDeleteLink** function) I've added html for modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">...some text...</h4>
          </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p><p class="debug-url"></p>
                <p>...some text...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">CANCEL</button>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">OK</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, hope it helps :)