# Passing a variable to a html modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I am trying to do the following.

1. When the user clicks on a button a modal should show up
2. The modal should show a different content depending on which button has been pressed
3. There are many buttons of that kind on my site. So I want to pass a variable to the modal and make an if comparison

Here is my modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="group_selection" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">

          <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Select the journal club for which this vote should count</h4>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
                <form>

                  {% for group in groups %}

                      <input class="group_sel" type="checkbox" value="{{ group[0] }}">{{ group[0] }}
                      </input><br>

                  {% endfor %} 
              </form>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
              <input class="btn btn-primary multivote" type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" value="Select" />
              <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" value="Close" />
          </div>  
      <!-- </form>  -->                                
  </div>
```

The modal above shows a selection of groups. This selection is the same for each modal, so that works fine, but now I want to disable the input statement in the for loop depending on which button has been pressed to get to this modal.

I don't know how to create new variables within html. I was hoping that jQuery can help with this, so I trigger the modal with the following jQuery command

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".vote").click(function(){ 
      $('#group_selection').modal('show');
   });
});
</script>
```

I know that I can use jQuery to write values into the html code (as shown here [Passing data to a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal)) but I don't see how I can use that to make an if selection?

Thanks for your help

best

carl

Answer (score 0):

Simply determine which of the `.vote` buttons were clicked and perform the appropriate task before showing the modal, i.e.:

```
$(".vote").click(function(){ 
      switch($(this).attr('value'))
      {
          case '5 Stars': // Assumes your button's value was '5 Stars'
            $('#group1').attr('disabled','disabled'); //disables group1 when 5 stars was selected  
               break; 
          case '4 Stars': ... break;
      }
      $('#group_selection').modal('show');
   });
```

Or, assign each different button a different `.click()` handler to execute the appropriate task.

Side Notes: You should also reset all the disables when the modal is opened and reset the form to make it fresh for each load as well

Comment: Hi carl K, thanks for your answer. What if the number of options needs to be dynamic? In my case its not just 5 stars, 4 stars etc. I have 10 items to vote on which are passed to the html code as a list. That list changes every day

Comment: @carl If the `.vote` buttons change, they must have some sort of logic associated with them that would have to be interpreted. Will there be a standard set of possible actions?

Comment: sorry I might have oversimplified the problem above. The point of the exercise is that one should never be able to vote twice for the same object and the same group. So I will pass a list of previous votes to the html which I calculated beforehand in python-flask. So I have a list of votes and a list of items to vote on. The length of both lists is dynamic. Each button is associated with a item and I know how to pass the item name to jquery. If I could access the list of votes in jquery I could do the comparison in jquery. Do you know how to access variables in jquery...

Comment: @carl I am a tad confused. Re: your last question, jQuery is part of javascript, therefore, you can use global variables in conjunction. For example, if you want to use a global variable as part of a jQuery selector, you can do it as such: `var myVar = 'stars'; $('#'+myVar);` will return the object with `id=stars`