# double action in one click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem using onClick, in the first click run one action for the second click the problem showing my click run two action and for the third click the action run three action and for the next click. whats the problem white my jquery?

My Button Click

```
<a id="detailproduct" href="'.URL.'#PopProductDetail" onclick="showdetailproduct('.$val->bid.')" data-toggle="modal">'.$val->product name.'</a>
```

this the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showdetailproduct(id){
    $('#PopProductDetail').on('shown.bs.modal',function(e) {
        utils.ViewPopProduct(id);
    });
    }

var utils = {};
    (function ($) {

          $.ajaxSetup({"error":function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert(textStatus);
              alert(errorThrown);
              alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);

          }});

        utils.ViewPopProduct =  function ViewPopProduct(id) {
            var data={id:id};
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                datatype:"json",
                url:"",
                data:data,
                datatype:"html",
                cache:false,
                success: function(data) {
                        data = JSON.parse( data ); 
                        $('#code').val(data.code);
                        $('#name').val(data.name);
                        $('#groupname').val(data.groupname);
                        $('#brand').val(data.brand);

                        $('#PopProductDetail').trigger("reset");
                        $("#detailproduct").unbind("click", ViewPopProduct);
                }
            });
        return false;
    };

    })(jQuery, window, document);

</script>
```

The Action url

```
http://example.com/product?id=34&_=1450341040382
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I change my subject question. :D

Comment: This isn't about double-clicking. This is about clicking something multiple times with each click = different action. Right?

Comment: You keep binding a new event everytime you click the link, try this: `$('#PopProductDetail').off('shown.bs.modal').on('shown.bs.modal'`...

Comment: @Pete still the same.

Comment: @Pete, Thanks thats work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your showdetailproduct method, you are subscribing one more time to the event:

```
$('#PopProductDetail').on('shown.bs.modal',function(e) {
```

This subscription should occur only one. Put the binder on `document.ready`. Onclick event is not necessary, the href is doing the trick.

Comment: if not use onclick how the proses GET the id?

Comment: the `'shown.bs.modal'` will be triggered when you click on the link, because of the `data-toggle` and the `href`. Is not related to the `onClick` event. You should set the listener of `shown.bs.modal` on `document.ready`.  You can get the ID through the `e` parameter coming in the function. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal

Comment: Ok you can mark my post as answer for future people then :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my Code if it is help full to you.

I can handle 2 function at one click

Html Code

```
 <input type="button" id="btnSave2" value="INSERT-UPDATE" title="Save" 
                onclick="return btnSave2_onclick()" />

 function btnSave2_onclick() 
 {

      var txtcategorycodeid = $("#txtcategorycodeid").val();
      var txtcategoryname = $("#txtcategoryname").val();
      var fuimg = $("#fuimg").val();
      var ddstatus = $("#ddstatus").val();
      var fuimgst;
      if (fuimg != '' ) {
          fuimgst = 'active';
      }
      if (fuimg == '') {
          fuimgst = 'inactive';
      }


      if (txtcategorycodeid == '' && txtcategoryname == ''
            && ddstatus == '---Select---') {

          alert("Enter All Fields");
          return false;

      }
      else {

          if (txtcategorycodeid == '') {
              alert("Enter categorycodeid");

              return false;
          }
          if (txtcategoryname == '') {

              alert("Req  categoryname");

              return false;
          }
          if (!txtcategoryname.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
              alert('categoryname Only alphabets are allowed');
              return false;
          }


          if (ddstatus == '---Select---') {
              alert("Enter status");

              return false;
          }
      }


      var fileUpload = $("#fuimg").get(0);
      var files = fileUpload.files;
      var test = new FormData();
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          test.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
      }
      $.ajax({
          url: "imguploadhandler.ashx",
          type: "POST",
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          data: test,
          // dataType: "json",
          success: function (result) {




      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "JKS_Service.asmx/productcategor1",
          data: "{categoryCodeId: '" + txtcategorycodeid + "'       ,categoryName:'" + txtcategoryname + "',status:'" + ddstatus + "',fupic:'"+fuimgst+"'}",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          datatype: "jsondata",
          async: "true",
          success: function (response) {
              $(".errMsg ul").remove();
              var myObject = eval('(' + response.d + ')');
              if (myObject > 0) {

                  alert("Data saved successfully...");

              }
              else {

                  alert("Not saved..");
              }

              clear();

          },
          error: function (response) {
              alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
          }
      });
  },


  });
  }
```