# Javascript id as parameter in href

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

[Second image ,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsycE.png)[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7l3Z.png) I have a set of links, which will open a pop-up form.
When the link is clicked,I want to send a parameter to the form and then use it on form submission.
I'm able to set the value to be passed as id of `<a>` tag. Can I send to further?

```html
<div> <span>Chapter $i:</span>
  <a href='$viewlink '>View</a><span class='status'>Status:$status </span>
  <a href=$reqlink id=$i data-rel='popup' class='ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left'>Request Access</a></div><br/>";
```

```html
<form method="post" action=" " id="myPopup" data-role="popup" style="padding:10px">

  <h3>Enter your details</h3>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
  <input type="date" name="date" id="date" placeholder="Intended completion date" required>
  <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit" name='submit'>

</form>
```

Is it possible to do in javascript? How to do it?

Comment: have you tried pushing the data to a javascript array, then add that array as query string to the form action on submit...? you'd have to prevent sending the form first, and only explicitly send it once you have taken care of the query string...

Comment: @Dee try this one might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal

Comment: Welcome to SO, use snipets only when you want to show full code that can run in the browser. use `{}` button or indent with 4 spaces if you want just show the code.

Comment: @jcubic Sorry! I'll follow next time on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option #1:**

Set up hidden inputs, and send the values to them when clicking the link. You can then get these on the other end where the form is sent.

(Note: in my code examples I'm explicitly using PHP as that's where you seem to have copied your code snipped from)

```php
echo "<a href='$viewlink' onclick='$(\'#viewlink\').val(1);'>View</a><span class='status'>Status:$status </span>

<!-- Do the following inside the form -->

<input type='hidden' name='viewlink' id='viewlink' value='0' />";
```

And on the PHP receiving end you can do this:

```php
if ($_POST['viewlink'] == 1) {
    // do stuff
}
```

---

**Option #2:**

Alternatively you could send the data to a javascript array, prevent posting on submit of the form, take care of adding the array to the form action as query string, then explicitly send the form.

```php
echo "<a href='$viewlink' onclick='linkClicked('viewlink');'>View</a><span class='status'>Status:$status </span>
```

This is what you'd do in your javascript file:

```javascript
var queryString = [];

function linkClicked (type) {
    queryString[type] = 1;
}

$("#myPopup").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('action', $(location).attr('host') + $.param(queryString));
    $(this).submit();
});
```

And on the PHP receiving end you can do the following (note the `$_POST` from above has changed to `$_GET`):

```php
if ($_GET['viewlink'] == 1) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I'll try doing it..Thank you @webeno

Comment: @weebo, Please see my images I have attached now. I want to send the chapter number dynamically during form submission.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I'll try it out now. But is it the efficient way to do what I intend to do

Comment: depending on what you mean by efficiency ;) these are 2 ways, but there sure are more...

Comment: let me know how the testing goes... ;)

Comment: I tried option #1, setting hidden input. It worked perfect 100%.

Comment: well, if that's the case, you may want to accept my answer as the correct one, hey, maybe even vote up! ;) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<a id = 'yourid' class = 'mybtn'>click me..</a>

<form id = 'myform'>
  ....
</form>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mybtn').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var SubmitForm = $("#myform").serializeArray();
        $.post("somepage.php",
        {
         SubmitForm:SubmitForm,
         ID:id
        },
        function(res){
            alert(res);//your result..
        });
});
```