# Passing button data to modal form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i came up from this link
[Passing data to a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal#) but yet still after hours, I cant find my way to do it on my own. I want to get the id of the button (let say i will do this via jsp) this is the button

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-id="p_id">Launch demo modal</a>
```

and here is the modal

```
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <input type="text" name="p_id" id="p_id" value=""/>
                                    <hr>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

With this `<script>` just above the button

```
$(document).on("click", "#myModal", function () {
     var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal-body #p_id").val( myBookId );
});
```

The ID should be display in the `<input type="text" name="p_id" id="p_id" value=""/>` I almost spend my whole night figuring this out.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector in the script is wrong. Try this

```
$(document).on("click", "a[href='#myModal']", function () {
     var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal-body #p_id").val( myBookId );
});
```

The problem was with this `"#myModal"` you were trying to trigger a click event of a element with `id = "myModal"` But in your case its the `href` value of the a tag and not the id. So I have changed the script to say `a[href='#myModal']`

Comment: Put a alert inside the click event and see if it fires. If it does and your input value is still empty that means there another instance of #p_id in your page.. It's must be unique.. Have a check

Answer (score 1):

Everything is OK except that you are using wrong selector. You are using **'#myModal** which is not the *id* for button you have. Use **a[href='#myModal']** instead.

Change your code to:

```
$(document).on("click", "a[href='#myModal']", function () {
     var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal-body #p_id").val( myBookId );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the link an `id` and then reference the link being clicked like so:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" id="myButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-id="p_id">Launch demo modal</a>

<script>
$(document).on('click','#myButton',function(){
    var myBookId = $(this).data('id);

    $('#p_id').val = myBookId;
});
</script>
```