# Pass ID into Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How do I pass ID from `<button>` into Bootstrap Modal. So I can use ID to get information from ajax to display in the Modal.

For example:

Button:

```
<button id="123" type="button" class="btn btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Testing">Edit</button>
```

Should I use `shown.bs.modal` do this?

```
$("#Testing").on('shown.bs.modal', function () { 
  // How to get ID? id="??"
  //Ajax
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data to a bootstrap modal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `event` object that is passed to the `show.bs.modal` handler.

```
$('#Testing').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var id = $(event.relatedTarget).attr('id');
});
```

`event.relatedTarget` refers to the button that has triggered the modal open event.

[**Bootstrap Documentation**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target)

Comment: Thank you. That work! Should I use null like this if (id != null) { }

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back If there are buttons which don't have `ID` attribute, you can use `if (!id)`