# Unable to access id pass to bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-modal

i want to update and delete the data from table using bootstrap modal window . i have passed id for that particuar data to be updated or delete. but iam not able to access that id into modal window. 
thanks in advance

here is my code

```
<!-- Delete Project Modal -->
    <div id="del-event-modal" class="modal fade">

        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">

                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

                    <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>

                </div><!--//modal-header-->

                <div class="modal-body">

                    <p class="text-warning">Do you want to Delete this project?</p>
                    <input type="text" value="" id="id">

                </div> <!--//modal-body-->

                <div class="modal-footer">

                 <!--   <button type="submit" name="del" class="btn btn-primary" id="del" onClick="document.location.href='delproject.php'" >OK</button>-->
                     <button type="submit" name="del" id="del" class="btn btn-primary" >OK</button>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>


                </div> <!--//Modal-footer -->

            </div><!--//modal-content-->

        </div><!--//modal-dialog-->

    </div><!--//modal-->
<!--// Delete Project Modal -->

<!-- edit project modal -->
  <div id="edit-event-modal" class="modal fade">

        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">

                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Project</h4>

                </div><!--//modal-header-->

                <div class="modal-body">
<?
       $id = $_POST["id"]; //escape the string if you like
        $query_selectDetails = "SELECT * FROM tblprojects WHERE ProID='$id'";
        $result_selectDetails = mysqli_query($conn,$query_selectDetails) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        $row_selectDetails = mysqli_fetch_array($result_selectDetails);


    if(isset($_POST['edit'])){

        $pronm = $_POST['pnm']; 
        $city = $_POST['pcity'];
        $insertFeature = "update tblprojects set ProName='$pronm' and City='$city' where ProID='$id'"; 
        $executeFeature = mysqli_query($conn,$insertFeature) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        $getProp = mysqli_fetch_array($executeFeature);
        //header("Location:projects.php");

    } 
?>
               <div>
                 <form action="" method="POST" class="form" id="add-department">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pnm" name="pnm" placeholder="Project Name" value="<?php echo $row_selectDetails['ProName']; ?>"/>
                      <span class="help-block"></span>
                      </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pcity" name="pcity" placeholder="City" value="<?php echo $row_selectDetails['City']; ?>"/>
                      <span class="help-block"></span>
                      </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                       <label>Feature : </label>
                          <textarea  class="form-control" id="p_feature" name="p_feature[]"> <? echo $row_selectDetails['Features']; ?> </textarea>
                          <span class="help-block"></span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Specification : </label>
                          <textarea class="form-control" id="p_spec" name="p_spec[]" > <?php echo $row_selectDetails['Specification']; ?> </textarea>
                          <span class="help-block"></span>
                          </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">

                      <input type="submit" id="edit" name="edit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update"/>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </div>
                </div> <!--//modal-body-->

                <div class="modal-footer">

                   <!-- <button type="submit" name="del" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="document.location.href='#'" >OK</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
-->

                </div> <!--//Modal-footer -->

            </div><!--//modal-content-->

        </div><!--//modal-dialog-->

    </div><!--//modal-->
<!--//edit project modal-->
    <div class="thumbnail search-thumbnail">
<!--                                                                <span class="search-promotion label label-success arrowed-in arrowed-in-right">Sponsored</span>
-->
<!--                                                                <img class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/100px200?theme=gray" />
-->                                                                                                                             <img class="media-object" src="<? if ($getProp['image']!='')echo $getProp['image'];else echo "holder.js/100px200?theme=gray"; ?>" />

                                                                <div class="caption">
                                                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                                                        <span class="pull-right label label-grey info-label"><? echo $getProp['City'];?></span>

                                                                        <!--<div class="pull-left bigger-110">
                                                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-star orange2"></i>

                                                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-star orange2"></i>

                                                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-star orange2"></i>

                                                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-star-half-o orange2"></i>

                                                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-star light-grey"></i>
                                                                        </div>-->

                                                                    </div>

                                                                    <h3 class="search-title">
                                                                        <a href="#" class="blue"><? echo $getProp['ProName']; ?></a>
                                                                    </h3>

                                                                    <p><span class="text-info">Features :</span>
                                                                     <? 
                                                                        $featureQry = "select * from tblfeature where ProID='$id'";
                                                                        $exefeatureQry = mysqli_query($conn,$featureQry);
                                                                        while($getFeature = mysqli_fetch_array($exefeatureQry)){ 
                                                                         echo $getFeature['Feature']; } ?>
                                                                    </p>
                                                                    <p><span class="text-info">Specification :</span>
                                                                     <? 
                                                                        $specificQry = "select * from tblspecification where ProID='$id'";
                                                                        $exespecificQry = mysqli_query($conn,$specificQry);
                                                                        while($getSpecific = mysqli_fetch_array($exespecificQry)){                                                                                                                                                                                                  echo $getSpecific['Specification']; echo "\n"; } ?>
                                                                    </p>
                                                                    <div class="action-buttons bigger-125" align="center">
                                                                            <a href="#edit-event-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<? echo $getProp['ProID']; ?>">
                                                                                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-edit green"></i>
                                                                            </a>

                                                                            <a href="#">
                                                                                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-heart red"></i>
                                                                            </a>

                                                                            <a href="#del-event-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<? echo  $getProp['ProID']; ?>">
                                                                            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                                            </a>
                                                                            <!--<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Delete Project</a>-->
                                                                </div>
                                                                </div> <!--//caption -->

                                                            </div> <!--// thumbnail -->

    $('#edit-event-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {

                 //get data-id attribute of the clicked element
                var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');

                //populate the textbox
                $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="proid"]').val(bookId);
                //var x = document.getElementById("proid").value; alert("pid"+x);


                /*$('#edit').on('click', function () {

                    var x = document.getElementById("proid").value;  
                    var pnm = document.getElementById("pnm").value;  
                    var pcity = document.getElementById("pcity").value;  
                    var spec = document.getElementById("p_spec").value;  

                     $.ajax({
                        url: 'editproject.php',
                        type: 'POST',                                               
                        cache: 'false',
                        data :{value:x,pnm:pnm,pcity:pcity,feature:feature,spec:pspec} ,
                        success: function(data){
                            var data = JSON.stringify(data)
                            //alert("id sent is "+data);    
                            window.location.href="projects.php";                                                       
                        }
                    });

                 });*/
            });

     $('#del-event-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

              var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
              var recipient = button.data('id'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
              // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
              // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
              var modal = $(this);

              modal.find('.modal-body #id').val(recipient);

                $('#del').on('click', function (event) {
                    var x = document.getElementById("id").value;  alert(x);
                     $.ajax({
                        url: 'delproject.php',
                        type: 'POST',                                               
                        data :{value:x} ,
                        success: function(data){
                        var data = JSON.stringify(data)
                        alert("id sent is "+data);  
                        //window.location.href="projects.php";                                                     
                        }
                    });

                 });
            });
```

Comment: which modal plugin?

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal

Comment: already seen this solution. they has sent static id to the modal but i nned to send the dynamic.