# button value pass to modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have dynamic table,  and in button value I store value of each id.
I need to pass that id to the modal and do some queries in modal. I will do that via php.

```
<td><button="type" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"  onclick="getNarudzbaId(this)" value="<?php echo $r['id'];?>" data-toggle="modal" id="modal" data-target="#modal_theme_success">Pregled <i class="fa fa-play position-right"></i></a></td>

<script type="text/javascript">

     function getNarudzbaId(object) {

         var x = $(object).attr("value");

           $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "pregled.php",
            data:{name:x}, 

            success: function(data){
                 alert("return here if success")

            }
        })
        }

    </script>
```

Actually I want to get passed value in modal window which is on the same page where buttons are.

Here is my modal

```
<div id="modal_theme_success" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header bg-success">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h6 class="modal-title">Stavke naloga</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <h6 class="text-semibold">Text in a modal</h6>
        <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>

        <hr>
            <?php
                $temp = $_POST['name'];
                echo $temp;
            ?>
        <h6 class="text-semibold">Another paragraph</h6>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        </div>  
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have never sent values to modal before, any help is very appreciated

Comment: Try reading this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal

Answer (score 1):

Concept is simple. First you need to get value and send request after that open modal window

```
<button id="btn" value="<?php echo $r['id'];?>"></button>
```

Get value of button via jQuery, send request

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
   var id = $(this).val();

   $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: 'pregled.php'
      data: {'name':id},
      success: function(data) {
        // Show returned data on Modal
        $('.modal-title').text(data.name); // ex: show result on title
      }
   });
});
```

Point is not sending value to Modal, It is about showing requested data on Modal according to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it this way, it could help someone if the similar issue occurs.

Button

```
td><button="type" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"  onclick="getNarudzbaId(this)" value="<?php echo $r['id'];?>" data-toggle="modal" id="modal" data-target="#modal_theme_success">Pregled <i class="fa fa-play position-right"></i></a></td>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">           
    function getNarudzbaId(object) {
        var x = $(object).attr("value");
        $.post('modal-body.php', {post:x}, 
        function(data) {
            $('#print').html(data);  // div where value is printed
        });
    }
</script>
```