# How to echo id value as variable in bootstrap modal window?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I thought this would be easy enough but it's giving me problems. I tried searching other answers to solve this­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­, but to no avail. I have a list of buttons where the id value is dynamic.­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-defau­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­lt notesButton" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>"
role="button">Notes</a>
```

­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­
Then have JavaScript where I want to opent the modal window and get the id as a variable that I can echo in the window or use in a query.­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".notesButton").click(function(){
        $("#notesModal").modal();
        var myOrderId = $(this).data('id');
    });
});
```

Finally, I try to echo myOrderId in the modal, or use it in a query. But, it doesn't show.

```
<div id="notesModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Order Notes</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <?php echo $myOrderId; ?>              

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end modal -->
```

Once I'm able to echo this value, then it should be easy to use it in an sql query inside the window, but for now I can't get the value to echo in the modal window. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Maybe this will help --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#notesModal").on("show.bs.modal", function(evt) {
    var $btn = $(evt.relatedTarget);
    var $modal = $(evt.target);
    var $content = $modal.find(".modal-body");

    $content.text( $btn.data("id") );
});
```

1. **PHP is server side language**, javascript is client-side language, so it is called afterwards.
2. **`var myOrderId` is javascript, not PHP variable**.

You can try it out here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s79ugsyL/)

Learn more about Bootstrap Modals in [documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/).

**EDIT:** Regarding SQL query:

If you want  to use your `id` as a paramter in SQL query when modal shows, again, **you do not do that client, but server side**. According to [varying modal content chapter of documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#varying-modal-content), general approach is:

1. Store varying data in the element which shows modal (you already do that with your `data-id`)
2. Now you have two different approaches:

   - POST AJAX call to your server within `.on('show.bs.modal', function(){})`  second parameter, where  you send the data you store in the button (`data-id`), query your DB server side and respond with required results, which you can use before modal shows in AJAX callback function;
   - prepare all the SQL data beforehand, render it as JSON document within element which `show.bs.modal`, as let's say `data-sql`, and then use it in the second parameter of `.on('show.bs.modal', function(){})`method, accessing it like: `$(evt.relatedTarget).data("sql")`;

Comment: This works with regard to displaying the correct id number in the modal body. But I assumed I could use that id number inside modal body and run an sql query. However, my query results are not displaying. So, I guess the modal doesn't know to automatically run the query when it opens.