# Add custom class from link to drupal-modal drupal 8 with bootstrap theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, drupal-8

In Drupal 8, with the bootstrap theme when you create a link with `class` and `data-dialog-type` attributes like the bellow code:

```
<a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal"
  href="http://drupal.page/front">text
</a>
```

You will open content of the page in `#drupal-modal` element that has these html wrappers:

```
<div id="drupal-modal" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: block;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content">
```

This structure is generated in: `\themes\bootstrap\js\modal.js` how we can see on the [link](https://gist.github.com/Yog/a9b899ca0b31cc39f5929a75d5317dd1).

How do I modify it so that I can pass a class name to the `#drupal-modal` element from the link `a.use-ajax`? The class name text could be value of an attribute of the link.

Specifically I'd like to add `modal-lg` or `modal-sm` classes or some custom ones.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Waxi i have read through the other issue and I came up with this:

```
$(document).on("mousedown", ".use-ajax", function () {
    var modalClass = $(this).data('dialog-class');
    $(document).on('show.bs.modal','.modal', function () {
        $('.modal-dialog',this).addClass("modal-" + modalClass);
    })
});
```

Had to use `mousedown` event, coz `click` wouldn't work as it is blocked by something. 
Then it is getting content of `data-dialog-class` so it can be added to the `.modal-dialog` element after the modal actually loads, because its html is not present before that

Answer (score 8):

data-dialog-options allows you to pass any options to [jQuery's Dialog Widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/). One of the options is `dialogClass` which allows you to set the class.

Example html:

```html
<a class="use-ajax" 
  data-dialog-type="modal" 
  data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:800, &quot;dialogClass&quot;: &quot;product-information-incorrect&quot;}" 
  href="#">Click me !</a>
```

No custom js needed.

Comment: The dialogClass option has been deprecated in favor of the classes option : 
https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-dialogClass

Answer (score 2):

My solution

HTML:

```
<a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" href="#" data-dialog-class="your-class">Click me !</a>
```

Javascript:

```
  var modalClass;

  $(document).on("mousedown", ".use-ajax", function () {
      modalClass = $(this).data('dialog-class');
      $(document).on('show.bs.modal','.modal', function () {
          $(this).addClass(modalClass);
      })
  });

  // Add this part to remove the class when the modal is closed.
  $(document).on('hide.bs.modal','.modal', function () {
      $(this).removeClass(modalClass);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

To add complementary information to the comments in this post, please see the below example. I use it to hide the title bar programmatically, but the custom class allows you to do the same or even more.

```
let dialog = Drupal.dialog('#idSelector', {
  'modal': true,
  'dialogClass': 'yourCustomClass',
  'create': function (event, ui) {
    $(ui).find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this for adding your custom class

data-dialog-options= '{"classes":{"ui-dialog":"your class name"}}'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).