# Passing variable's value to modal box in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-modal

I want to pass a variable value to a modal box I call on the same page but have not been able to do it.

Code to open modal box is as below

```
<li style="font-style:bold" title="rate on skill" class="skill_rating">
<a data-toggle="modal" title="Add this item" class="open-AddBookDialog" href="#addBookDialog" data-id='<?php echo $skill_id2[$q]?>'>
<i class="fa fa-anchor" aria-hidden="true"></i>  </a><?php echo $skilltemp2[$q2] ?></li>
```

Modal Box code as below

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addBookDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addBookDialog"><div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Search</h4>    
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value=""/>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span>Search</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript before the closing body tag is as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
 var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
 $(".modal-body #bookId").val( myBookId );
      });
 </script>
```

I saw a couple of answers at stackoverflow (like:[Passing data to a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal) )but I have not been able to customize it as per my requirement.

Pardon me if its is too simple. I am a noob

Comment: Do you want to pass variable value to your modal box or you want to pass variable?

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar variable value

Comment: Your JavaScript is wrong. You have attached "click" event to document. So whenever you click on page the script will run. And you need to learn scoping of "this" in jQuery events. In your case "this" will represent "document" and hence your customization won't work.

Comment: Can you suggest something that works? @PratikGaikwad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript variables and modal box's value of bookId need to be re-defined. A possible use case as below.

Body Code

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#takeaction" class="btn btn-default"></a>
```

Modal Box

```
<div class="modal fade" id="takeaction" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Display Apply Id in modal box in a dynamic way? </h4>    
    </div>
    <div class="form-inline container hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <input type="number" value="<?php echo $apply?>" class="form-group" placeholder="Job Code"> 
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span>Confirm</span></button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#takeaction').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
var apply = $(e.relatedTarget).data('apply');
$(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="apply"]').val(apply);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is working in my case. Yes it is not in PHP but i have put static value for  Data-Id.

```
$('body').on('click', '.open-AddBookDialog', function() {
     var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
     $("#addBookDialog #bookId").val( myBookId );
});
```

Example [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/195/)

Comment: No, I want a variable value to be passed to the modal box

Comment: Now you can set any variable value in input just you need to pass that variable on behalf of myBookId  variable.