# Pass parameter from one link to another with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site where I am triggering a modal from a set of links. Is there a way to pass a reference of the link itself to the modal?

My current implementation is available here: http://138.197.123.25/ the left sidebar links will simply launch a modal window and ask for location; when they choose a location for that specific item.

The problem is if someone clicks on the side menu for `Party Packages`, then chooses say `San Diego` from the modal choice, they are taken to `http://138.197.123.25/location/san-diego-rentals/`, but what I would like is for them to go directly to the item and location they chose, so in this example, I would like them to go to directly to `http://138.197.123.25/location/san-diego-rentals/party-packages/`.

I am not sure how to pass a reference of the link that is clicked to launch the modal, so I can add the type of item to the location and build the final URL.

Comment: I cleaned up your question and removed references to django, since it is not relevant to your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data to a bootstrap modal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: Have you tried using the `data-*` attribute? That could work. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Answer (score 0):

@burhan-khalid Thank you for the link; that helped me greatly.  Here is my working code with the sidebar data param being append to an href in the modal.

**sidebar static menu (initiates modal) - link 1**

Currently there are about 20 sidebar links that open the modal, and each have a `data` attribute assigned. The link below has a data attribute of `data-pr` but others have custom attributes like `data-cg (carnival games) or data-tp (themed-parties)` etc...

```
...
<div class="ss_button" data-id="party-packages"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Party Packages</a></div>
...
```

**modal window with 1 of four link choices (initiates modal) - link 2**

```
...
<div class='col-md-3'>
   <a href="/location/san-diego-rentals/"><span class='city'>San Diego</span></a>
</div>
...
```

**script**

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".ss_button", function () {
        var rentals = $(this).data('id');
        $('.modal-content a').attr('href', function () {
            return this.href + rentals;

        });
    });
</script>
```