# Pass data attribute to modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

```
<a class="my_link" data-val="user1" href="#">modal link</a>
```

I have this link to open a bootstrap modal, but I need to pass data attribute "data-val". I tried with javascript but I didn't get it. Can you please help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data to a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: You need to set `href` or `data-toggle` attribute of link to the `id` of the modal with a `#` symbol in front of it. Anyways, a working example is in answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can listen for `show.bs.modal` event on modal and get the clicked element available as `relatedTarget` property of the event. Check Bootstrap modal [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/) for further reference.

Here is a working example using Bootstrap v4.

```js
$('#my-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var myVal = $(event.relatedTarget).data('val');
  $(this).find(".modal-body").text(myVal);
});
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a href="#" class="my_link" data-val="user1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my-modal">Open Modal</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="my-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="my-modal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">My Modal</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery, Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I saw this function but didn't bother to look into it because of its name, why is it called `relatedTarget`?

Answer (score -2):

You can just set up the modal

```
<div  class="modal fade" id="setTypeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Then call it with

```
 $('#setTypeModal').modal('show');
```

You can then access the elements in the modal using Jquery etc.

and finally do some more work with a click event and close the modal with

```
 $('#setTypeModal').modal('hide');
```