# pass data-id to the modal in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to edit user data in my application. I have edit button as below.

```
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactEditFormModal" data-id="<%= t["id"] %>">
        Edit
    </button>
```

how can I pass this data-id to my modal in rails.

Comment: with a little help of google and thanks to malviya: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45733078/4969349