# How to maintain the state of a sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building my first web application I have 2 navigation menu
-Navbar
-Sidebar

When I'm navigating my application with my navbar, I'm not using my sidebar for that reason I hide it, but this every time I enter a page always shows active, I want to avoid this.

Example I'm on my homepage, I'm not using my sidebar, I click to hide my sidebar, I go to the contact page, and the sidebar is activated again.

I want the sidebar to maintain its status, if it is hidden that is kept hidden, if the sidebar is active that remains active.
Link source code
https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
/*
    DEMO STYLE
*/

@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #7386D5;
    background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>Collapsible sidebar using Bootstrap 4</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar  -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
            </div>

            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <p>Dummy Heading</p>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/files/sidebar.zip" class="download">Download source</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar" class="article">Back to article</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <!-- Page Content  -->
        <div id="content">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                        <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                        <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-dark d-inline-block d-lg-none ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact click here</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <h2>Collapsible Sidebar Using Bootstrap 4</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <div class="line"></div>

            <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <div class="line"></div>

            <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <div class="line"></div>

            <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Popper.JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Read up on how to use `localStorage`. Store state there and retrieve on each page load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a way to "remember" the sidebar display setting as you navigate from page to page. Using variables is not an option, since each page is a tabula rasa (a *blank slate*, so to speak) - all variables are reset. However, here are three options:

1. #### LocalStorage

Probably the easiest/best option. LocalStorage is a way to store variables *in the browser itself*, sorted by domain name. Therefore, you can store a LocalStorage "variable" on one page and then read it back from any other page on that same domain. It is literally as simple as [this:](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

IMPORTANT: Also note that you (or anyone) can view the contents of the local storage variables in Chrome like this:
(a) <kbd>F12</kbd>  (Opens Dev Tools window)
(b) <kbd>Application</kbd> (on top nav bar tab/menu)
(c) Expand `Local Storage >` (under *Storage* section of left-side panel)
(d) Click on appropriate domain (all LocalStorage data is stored by domain)
(e) You will see the `key` and `value` data for each localStorage pair

THEREFORE: If *some* degree of opacity is desired when using localStorage, a common ploy is to use seemingly-nonsense variable names and data (i.e. they are nonsensical to anyone snooping, but *you* know what they mean). For example, instead of storing:

```
key=sidebar     value=off
```

you can store:

```
key=asdfasdf     value=19234324
```

2. #### Send the information to the next page as a form

In javascript, it is reasonably straight-forward to create a bit of HTML and inject it onto the page. So, for example, you could create a form element containing an input field that contains the desired information - and immediately after injecting it on to the page - POST that form to the next page. Of course, the next page would need to contain PHP code that receives the data from the `$_POST[]` variable and acts on it (by re-hiding the side nav), but that is the overview of how this would work.

Here is a code example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myFrm = $('<form action="form2.html"><input name="sidebar" value="off" /></form>');
    myFrm.appendTo('body').submit();
});
```

3. #### AJAX back/forth with server

You could also use AJAX to store the current variable state on the server. Although localhost is a simpler way to handle this present situation, it is important to know of the AJAX option. One day it might be the correct option (for example, if security is involved where only approved visitors should be able to do something). In a nutshell: AJAX is a javascript methodology (quite simple really, especially with jQuery) that allows you to send/receive data from the server without navigating away from (OR refreshing) the current page. This allows you to, for example, ask something from the user, send it to the server where something is done (such as a database lookup), receive the data back from the server, and then javascript can change the DOM based on the information received back.

#### References:

[See multiple references at bottom of this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37105645/1447509)

[Local Storage and How To Use It On Websites](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/)

[MDN LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

[Dynamically create and submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003089/dynamically-create-and-submit-form)

[Simple AJAX Example and Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54815729/pass-var-to-bootstrap-modal-where-php-will-use-this-value/54816127#54816127)

Answer (score 1):

I added class `collapseSideBar` to the links you want to close the side bar

```
$('#sidebarCollapse, .collapseSideBar').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sidebarCollapse, .collapseSideBar').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
/*
    DEMO STYLE
*/

@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #7386D5;
    background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>Collapsible sidebar using Bootstrap 4</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar  -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
            </div>

            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <p>Dummy Heading</p>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="collapseSideBar">Home 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="collapseSideBar">Home 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="collapseSideBar">Home 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="collapseSideBar" data-toggle="collapse"">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="collapseSideBar">Page 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="collapseSideBar">Page 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="collapseSideBar">Page 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="collapseSideBar">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="collapseSideBar">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/files/sidebar.zip" class="download">Download source</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar" class="article">Back to article</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <!-- Page Content  -->
        <div id="content">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                        <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                        <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-dark d-inline-block d-lg-none ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact click here</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <h2>Collapsible Sidebar Using Bootstrap 4</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <div class="line"></div>

            <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <div class="line"></div>

            <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <div class="line"></div>

            <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Popper.JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use session (classic javascript)

1. On collapse and un-collapse save sidebar status as 'c' or 'o' (closed or opened)
   sessionStorage.setItem('sSidebarStatus', 'c');
2. Read on page load or $(document).ready(function ()

   if (sessionStorage.getItem('sSidebarStatus') == 'o' || sessionStorage.getItem('sSidebarStatus') == null) {
   //add active class to side bar or remove it
   //if you want working example let me know, hope this helps
   }

You may also want NO animation during above code as use has not clicked for sidebar

$(' .collapsing').css('transition', 'none'); //ON page load stop animation of menu