# Passing data from a buttton to a modal boostrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I a button element on a page that opens a modal both are the same page , and i want to pass data from the button to a modal when it is opened. Is there a way achieving that functionaly without or with javascript/jquery ?
Here is the html snippets of my markup

```html
<button class="btn-icone bg-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaleIcones"
      data-id=1235> 
      <i value=Radiology class="fa fa-edit"></i>                                                                                      </button>
      
      
<div class="modal fade" id="modaleIcones">
    <div class="modal-dialog" >
        <div class="modal-header">
            
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <a href="#" id="iconLink1">
               <img src="myImg.png">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to pass *data-id=1235* from the button to the modal-body anchor element with *id="iconLink1"*. I would appreciate any help

Comment: you cant pass data without JS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data to a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jquery and Bootstrap modals (tested with version 4) you could do sth like this:

```
$('[data-toggle="modal"]').on('click.modal.data-api', function(event) {
  var targetModal = $($(this).data('target'));
  var content = $(this).data('content');
  targteModal.find('.modal-content').html(content);
}
```

You could for example just save  a template filename in the data-content attribute and load this with jquery loadtemplate.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use JS/jQuery for this.

I won't give you the exact code, but here are the steps for you to follow:

1. Give your button an `id` so you can identify through your JS code which DOM element you wish to manipulate/get data from. e.g. `<button id='myButton'>`
2. Get the element with `document.getElementById('#myButton')`.
3. Get its `data-id` attribute with the jQuery function: `.attr("data-id")`. Store it to a variable if you wish.
4. In the modal, you now have access to the data-id, either from the variable you stored it to, or from making the call directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would do with this Jquery by on click of the button get the attribute value of `'data-id'`, adding it to a variable and then setting the href element of the `a` tag with the id `iconLink1`

```
$('#myButton').click(function() { 
    var _data = $(this).attr('data-id'); 
    $('#iconLink1').attr('href' , _data);
});
```

You could also check the click by adding a `console log(_data);` after decalaring the new variable