# How to fix this code to popup bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup

try to get bootstrap popup window by click the **UPDATE link** using following code but given errors how to fix it

```
    $(function() {
        $.get("/Home/GetData",
            {},
            function(data) {
                var row;
                $.each(data,
                    function(i, v) {
                        row += "<tr><td>" +
                            v.id +
                            "</td><td>" +
                            v.Name +
                            "</td><td>" +
                            v.Password +
                            "</td><td>" +
                            v.Email +
                            "</td><td>" +
                            v.Address +
                            "</td><td>" +
                            v.City +
                            "</td><td><a href='/home/Update?id=" +
                            v.id +
                            "' data-target="#
                        updatemodal
                        " data-toggle="
                        modal
                        ">UPDATE</a></td><td><a href='/home/DeleteRecord?id=" + v.id + "'>Delete</a></td></tr>"
                    });
                $("#tbldata").append(row);
            });
    });
```

i add this to code UPDATE 
do that but not work how to fix it

Comment: What errors? Please take a few minutes to read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Change you `$.each` function to

```
$.each(data,
    function (i, v) {
        $("#tbldata tbody").append("<tr />");
        $($("#tbldata tbody tr")[i]).append(`<td>${v.id}</td>`);
        $($("#tbldata tbody tr")[i]).append(`<td>${v.Name}</td>`);
        $($("#tbldata tbody tr")[i]).append(`<td>${v.Password}</td>`);
        $($("#tbldata tbody tr")[i]).append(`<td>${v.Email}</td>`);
        $($("#tbldata tbody tr")[i]).append(`<td>${v.Address}</td>`);
        $($("#tbldata tbody tr")[i]).append(`<td>${v.City}</td>`);
        $($("#tbldata tbody tr")[i])
            .append(`<td> <a href="/home/Update?id=${v.id}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">UPDATE</a></td>`);
        $($("#tbldata tbody tr")[i])
            .append(`<td><a href="/home/DeleteRecord?id=${v.id}">Delete</a></td>`);
});
```

I believe this is neater

Comment: popup window opened but data not load for select id

Comment: Your original question did not have the data to load? it does not even have the popup, I just assumed that the popup was there. If you want to pass data to the modal, then consider using `data-id`

Comment: '<td> <a href="#" data-id="${v.id}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Updatemodal">UPDATE</a></td>' try like these but not worked

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal