# How to pass data to bootstrap modal?

Tags: codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

Hi i'm trying delete operations on a table. I have added a bootstrap modal to confirm the action but I think cant able to pass the value cuz its always delete the first row data but when i using href from dropdown menu its work it just dont have bootstrap modal
Here my code is as follow:-

```
<tbody>
                    <?php $i = 1 + (6 * ($currentPage - 1)); ?>
                    <?php foreach ($surat as $s) : ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td scope="row"><?= $i++; ?></td>
                            <td><?= $s['no_sm'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $s['pengirim'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $s['tgl_sm'] ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-list"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                        <a href="/suratmasukdetail/<?= $s['id']; ?>" class="dropdown-item">Detail</a>
                                        <a href="/suratmasuk/delete/<?= $s['id']; ?>" class="dropdown-item">Hapus</a>
                                        <a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="dropdown-item">Modal</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                        <!-- Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modelTitleId" aria-hidden="true">
                            <form action="/suratmasuk/delete/<?= $s['id']; ?>" method="post">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            Apakah anda yakin ingin menghapus data ini?
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Kembali</button>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Hapus</button>
                                            <a href="/suratmasuk/delete/<?= $s['id']; ?>" class="dropdown-item">Hapus</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing data to a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: can u explain how to do that?

Comment: please check the link I shared.