# Can I use a hyperlink in a callback-generated DataTable to open a modal using passed data?

Tags: python, bootstrap-modal, plotly-dash

I create records in a DataTable using a `dbc.Modal` and a Submit button linked to a callback that invokes a POST request (there's 8 fields, showing only 2 for brevity):

```
html.Div([
    dbc.Modal([
        html.Tr([html.Td('Author(s):', id='country-source-author-label'),
        html.Td(dcc.Textarea(id='country-source-author-textarea')
        ]),
        html.Tr([html.Td('Publication Date:',
        html.Td(dcc.DatePickerSingle(id='country-source-publication-date-picked')])
    ], id='add-country-source-modal'),
    dbc.Button("Submit", id='add-country-source-submit-button'))
])
```

Here's sample data generated by this form:
`county_source_table = ['author_name': 'E.O. Wilson', 'date': '2021-10-31', 'link': '#']`

To view Sources, I have a DataTable with a hyperlink to an individual record in a Details column.

```
sources_table = dash_table.DataTable(
    id='county-source-table',
    columns=[
        {'id': 'author_name', 'name': 'Author'},
        {'id': 'date', 'name': 'Publication Date'},
        {'id': 'link', 'name': 'Details', 'type': 'text', 'presentation': 'markdown'}
    ], 
    markdown_options={'link_target': '_self'})
```

What I'd like to do is click on the link for each record in the table to open up the Dash Bootstrap modal with all the relevant data for that record - something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal). I'm stumped - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Plotly Community members Eduardo and AnnMarieW [posted a method to treat DataTable cells as buttons](https://community.plotly.com/t/button-inside-a-dash-table/51460) using the `active_cell` property of the table as an Input for the callback. This does the trick.