# Update table html with modal information

Tags: php, html

I have a page that has a table with 3 columns, two of which are data and the third has an edit button. When I click this button, the name is sent to a modal where it can be changed.
I need to do two things:
Update the name in the table and close the modal when click the Save Changes button on the modal.
Is it possible to do that?

**Index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        
        <!--CSS Bootstrap-->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
        <!-- JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        

    </head>

    <body>
            
            
            <table id="tabela">
              <thead>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th></th>
                
              </thead>
              <tr>
                 <td>1</td>
                 <td class="name">Fred</td>
                 
                 <td><button class="btnEdit">Edit</button></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>2</td>
                 <td class="name">Charles</td>
                 
                 <td><button class="btnEdit">Edit</button></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>3</td>
                 <td class="name">John</td>
                 
                 <td><button class="btnEdit">Edit</button></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            
            
            
        <div class="modal" id="modalTest" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
          <?php
            include "modalTabela.php";
          ?>
        </div>

        
        <script>
            //send name to php page
            $(".btnEdit").click(function() {
                var nome = $(this).closest('tr').find(".name").text();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '//localhost/tabela/modalTabela.php',
                    data: {msg: nome },
                  }).done(function(data) {
                    //update html
                    $("#modalTest").html(data);
                    //show modal
                    $("#modalTest").modal("show");
                  });   
            });
            
            

        </script>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

**modalTabela.php**

```
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <?php
                    $nome=$_POST['msg'];
                    echo "<label>Name</label><input type='text' id='edNome' value='$nome'></input>";
                ?>
                
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSalvar">Save changes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal