# Pass a parameter to a Vue Bootstrap Modal Dialog

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm using

```
"bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
 "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
 "vue": "^2.6.12",
```

In a Vue app and I need to pass a parameter to a Bootstrap Modal Dialog.  My code is:

```
    <input      
      v-b-modal.modal-center
      role="button"
      class="btn btn-link"
      type="button"          
      value="Edit"
      aria-disabled="false"
      style="height: 40px; width: 120px; background-color: #efefef; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 4px; cursor: pointer;"
    />
```

And I want to pass a centeredTitle to the dialog to be displayed on the header and tell it what JSON file to convert to an array to read.

```
     <b-modal id="modal-center" size="xl" @shown="onModalShown" @ok="onModalOk">
     <template slot="modal-title">{{ centeredTitle }}</template>
```

If I set the centeredTitle in code it shows fine.  But I want to use the same dialog for different areas but with a different title.

if I

```
      onModalShown() {
      // Clear the year and data fields
      if (this.firstModalshow) {
      //  this.centeredTitle ='Education and Training',
        this.newYear = '';
        this.newData = '';
        this.$refs.yearInput.focus();
        this.tempItem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.EducationTraining));
        this.firstModalshow = false;
      }
      
    },
```

and uncomment the this.centeredTitle my code will not run and gives a blank screen but it does compile.

I've read  [Passing data to a bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal)

but I can't get it to work in Vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `v-model` instead of the `v-b-modal.xxx` syntax, and set it in the button's `click` event. This will allow you to set some properties first, which the modal can then reference.

Your modal needs a `v-model`:

```
 <b-modal v-model="showModal" ... >
```

Your button needs a proper click handler:

```
  <input      
      @click="OnEditClicked"
      role="button"
     ...
    />
```

And your click handler will look like this:

```
    OnEditClicked() {
      this.centeredTitle ='Education and Training';
      //Other properties which the modal needs... 
      this.showModal = true;
    }
```